# Where to put PowerShell scripts?

Tags: powershell

(I can't believe I'm actually asking this, but I am out of brainpower for the day.)

I just wrote my first serious PowerShell script, and I'm really happy with it. I plan to use it every day or so. I want to be able to call it from the Posh command line. I'll give it a verb-noun type name, but for now it's a simple .ps1 and not one of those fancy advanced functions that take params and such.

So where should it go and how do I call it from a Posh command line? I plan to write more! Where should they go?

- Should it be a function in my profile?
- Should it go on my path?
- Does it go in a PSMODULEPATH? What kind of stuff goes there anyway? Does it look recursively or is it just like the normal PATH?

Where do you all put your PowerShell scripts and how do you organize them? I've got a lot of experience making C# and C++ tools and know what to name them and where to put them. And at the other extreme I've done a lot of crappy .bat files which are usually standalone or piled in a heap in some folder. But PowerShell seems to be very different. You can make crappy .bat file type things in it really quickly, or you can be building libraries and sophisticated services with it.

I'd really love some ideas on how I should start organizing these things before I start. Obviously everybody is different, so I'm hoping for some discussion. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to reconsider the best solution based on all other answers provided lately.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I put my personal scripts in the same folder as my profile.  I can then back up & version them together.  My profile begins with:

```
$ProfileRoot = (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$env:path += ";$ProfileRoot"
```

Comment: use $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path, see [source path of an executing script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801967/how-can-i-find-the-source-path-of-an-executing-script/6985381#6985381).  You get into problems with nested callers, even with the profile script, for example I have a helper function to reload your profile (after function/variable edits) but skip all one-time init (like loading .NET assemblies).

Comment: Is this script idempotent? Or would you potentially be re-appending the same directory over and over each time you ran it?

Answer (score 20):

My recommendations:
- Store the script in a directory as you wish, e.g. c:\posh
- Add the directory to $env:path

```
$env:path += ";c:\posh"
```

This ensures that you may be in other directory, say c:\windows, but you can call the script

```
[c:\windows] > sampl[TAB] # it expands the name of file to sample.ps1, then hit enter
```

If your file sample.ps1 contains functions definitions and you import it every time, then I would consider adding this line to your $profile file

```
. c:\posh\sample.ps1
```

Concerning script organization.. just several dirs according to the purpose of the scripts :) Personal, dev, external (downloaded), samples,...

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer, and it works. Plus it doesn't screw up your personal organization. As far as backups, etc. These are very custom, and so its case by case where you should store scripts for backup, etc. Plus "backup" isn't really pertinent to the question :).

Answer (score 19):

With V2, you can create a modules directory in the WindowsPowerShell directory where your profile is. PS will automatically look in that directory to load modules when you run import-module. I created a "Scripts" directory under WindowsPowerShell as well that is a sibling directory of Modules.

I use my profile to set some directories using variables with the following code:

```
PS>  cat $Profile
$scripts = "$(split-path $profile)\Scripts"
$modules = "$(split-path $profile)\Modules"
$docs    =  $(resolve-path "$Env:userprofile\documents")
$desktop =  $(resolve-path "$Env:userprofile\desktop")

PS> cat variable:\scripts
C:\Users\andy.schneider\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts

PS>  cat variable:\modules
C:\Users\andy.schneider\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

Comment: This is what I do as well.  Though I also have a "Libraries" directory with scripts that my profile auto executes to define global functions.  I did that in PowerShell v1, I will probably replace all that with Modules eventually.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I do:

note: substitute "ModuleName" for something meaningful.

Create a module and save it in the global modules folder as
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ModuleName\ModuleName.psm1". e.g.:

```
function global:FancyFunction() {
   # do something interesting here.
}

Export-ModuleMember -function FancyFunction
```

Open your powershell profile and add the following line to make sure that your module is loaded every time you start a powershell session:

```
Import-Module ModuleName -Force
```

You can easiliy find your powershell profile by typing:

```
notepad $profile
```

When you open a new powershell session, you should be able to call your function from the console or from other scripts without having to do anything else.

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` is now a legacy path and shouldn't be used any more.

Answer (score 2):

There is an exported variable in PowerShellGet module used in powershell 7.1

```
$PSGetPath
```

it has 4 properties

```
AllUsersModules    : C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules
AllUsersScripts    : C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Scripts
CurrentUserModules : C:\Users\username\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
CurrentUserScripts : C:\Users\username\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts
```

you could use one of those script locations. `Install-Script` is using them also.

Comment: what is the correct name of the variable?

Comment: @VladislavBorovikov `$PSGetPath` is the correct variable, but it only exists in PWSH 7.x (don't know about PWSH 6.x).

Comment: It doesn't exist. Please provide the link to the official documentation describing this variable.

Comment: this variable is a part of external module that is responsible for package management ```Import-Module PowerShellGet;
$PSGetPath```

Comment: if you can upgrade older powershell runtime with latest version of ```PowershellGet``` (I use 2.2.5 version) it will be available even in Windows PowerShell 5. this variable is official it is specified in the module manifest ```ExportedVariables``` field

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would distribute your code using advanced functions in modules. But if you for some obscure reason don't want to have your scripts to behave as built-in commands, you can distribute script files instead.

Scripts can be installed from a registered `PSRepository` (such as PS Gallery or one of your own, see `Register-PSRepository`) using the command `Install-Script`.

```
Install-Script -Repository PSGallery -Name Write-HelloWorld
```

You can select the installation directory to be used by specyfing `-Scope`

- `-Scope CurrentUser` will install the script to
  `$ENV:UserProfile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts`
- `-Scope AllUsers` will install the script to
  `$ENV:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts`

For PowerShell 7.x the paths will be

- `-Scope CurrentUser` will install the script to
  `$ENV:UserProfile\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts`
- `-Scope AllUsers` will install the script to
  `$ENV:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\Scripts`

(The scripts folder doesn't exist for PowerShell 7 untill you try installing a script for the first time.)

Instead of using a PowerShell repository and `Install-Script` you could of course copy the script directly to the preferred script folder.

The `$ENV:Path` variable, of course, needs to include the path to the script folder.

The difference will be that `Get-InstalledScript` will only display scripts that got the corresponding XML-description file, copied to the folder `InstalledScriptInfos`, as part of `Install-Script` command usage.

Comment: Note that `$ENV:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts` isn't in the path until the first time install-script runs.

Comment: Also worth nothing that scripts can act like advanced functions too (despite the latter's name, there can also be advanced _scripts_), so there's no strict need to use a module for distributing a single command.