# Path of currently executing powershell script

Tags: powershell

How do I do this in PowerShell.  In a batch file I would do:
%~d0%~p0

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801967/how-can-i-find-the-source-path-of-an-executing-script

Comment: By the way, you could shorten that to %~dp0

Answer (score 46):

For `PowerShell 3.0` users - following works for both modules and script files:

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath
}
```

Answer (score 37):

From [Get-ScriptDirectory to the Rescue](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/06/19/get-scriptdirectory.aspx) blog entry ...

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
  $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
  Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}
```

Comment: See also the answer at the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6985381/60620

Comment: link in answer => 404

Answer (score 17):

```
Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
```

Comment: What's `$MyInvocation`?

Comment: @alex [`$MyInvocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#myinvocation) is an automatic variable created by PowerShell. From the docs (linked): `Contains information about the current command, such as the name, parameters, parameter values, and information about how the command was started, called, or invoked, such as the name of the script that called the current command.`

Answer (score -14):

In powershell 2.0

split-path $pwd

Comment: Wroking directory is not the same as scripts directory.