# Powershell module and invoking files

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file

I have a script based powershell module (.psm1) and I have it imported into my main script. This module however needs to call a batch file that is located inside its same directory but apparently it is unable to see it. Currently the function in question looks like this:

```
function MyFunction
{
    & .\myBatch.bat $param1 $param2
}
```

How can I make the function see the batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is the current working directory, not the directory in which the module resides. The latter can be determined via the [`MyInvocation` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1183197/1630171). Change your function to this:

```
function MyFunction {
  $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
  $dir = Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
  $cmd = Join-Path $dir "myBatch.bat"
  & $cmd $param1 $param2
}
```

Comment: Why are you accessing **MyInvocation** in the parent scope? Wouldn't it be defined in the local (script) scope? I tested this and it doesn't work - the **.Path** property is null. I'd just access **$MyInvocation** directly from the script with no scope modifiers.

Comment: The function is defined in a module, and he needs the path of that module, not of the script importing the module.

Comment: I suggest a more compact version: `& (Join-Path (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) 'myBatch.bat') $param1 $param2`

Comment: @AdiInbar My answer has separate statements, because that way it's clearer what each step does. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function MyFunction {
  & (Join-Path (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) 'myBatch.bat') $param1 $param2
}
```