# PowerShell: Is it possible to write a script which refers to files in its folder, which will still work wherever it's called from?

Tags: powershell, directory

So let's say I have a script at C:\scripts\MyScript.ps1 which is simply:

```
Get-Content ".\text.txt"
```

In C:\scripts I also have a file, text.txt, which contains arbitrary text which gets printed when the script is called. This script works fine if I use it when PowerShell's current directory is C:\scripts. However, if PowerShell is currently in a different directory, e.g. C:\otherFolder, then calling the script thusly from the PoSh command window fails:

```
PS C:\otherFolder> ..\scripts\MyScript.ps1
```

which I would expect since the reference to text.txt within the script is relative and the file not present in C:\otherFolder. My question is, is there any way to write a script which has relative references to other files, which will still work as intended even if called from within a different folder?

I realize there wouldn't be a problem if the script referred to "C:\scripts\text.txt", but I want to be able to move the script (and it's dependent files) around without having to update the references in the script each time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this related StackOverflow question provides an answer:
[How to get the current directory of the cmdlet being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343767/how-to-get-the-current-directory-of-the-cmdlet-being-executed)

You'll probably want to use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` within your script

Comment: Didn't find that when I searched, but it works great, so thanks. Have flagged my question so hopefully someone will mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

try this in your script:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$path = join-path $dir "text.txt"
get-content $path
```