# How can I place variable in a folder path?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to copy a file to the current logged in user. The code below I think will work but I need to replace "username" with the variable $CurrentLoggedinUser.

C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security 
to something like this
C:\Users\$CurrentLoggedinUser\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security

Any idea how I can do this? TIA

```
$CurrentLoggedinUser = $env:UserName
Copy-Item -Path **/*.CERTS -Destination C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
```

Comment: `$env:UserProfile + '\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security'`

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Directory` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343767/how-to-get-the-current-directory-of-the-cmdlet-being-executed)

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Perhaps you meant `Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` to get the script's folder? Or, in PSv3+, `$PSScriptRoot`?

Comment: Probably, I'm not a very advanced Powershell user. The command I suggested worked when I tested it but maybe I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more generally about **how to incorporate variable references into command arguments / strings**:

In the simplest case, simply replace literal parts with `$var` references, where `var` is the name of the variable of interest:

```
C:\Users\$CurrentLoggedinUser\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
```

For added robustness, enclose the name in `{...}` so that subsequent chars. cannot be mistaken for part of the name:

```
C:\Users\${CurrentLoggedinUser}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
```

Of course, you can *directly* reference environment variables too:

```
C:\Users\${env:USERNAME}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
```

Or, given that the current user's profile dir. is accessible as `$env:USERPROFILE`:

```
$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
```

---

All of the above work as an *argument* to a *command*, that is to say, in when parsing in *argument mode* rather than *expression mode* - see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

In *expression mode*, you need to *quote* strings such as the ones above; in order to incorporate variable references (or even the output from entire commands via `$(...)`), you must *double*-quote them (which makes them so-called *expandable* strings - see [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)).

Note only do quoted strings work in argument mode too, their use may be necessary for strings that contain characters that have special meaning in argument mode, such as `&`, `@`, or `>`.

Thus, the equivalent of the above is simply:

```
"$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security"
```