# How does PowerShell treat "." in paths?

Tags: windows, powershell, path, relative-path, working-directory

Consider the following sequence of commands upon opening a PowerShell terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\username> cd source
PS C:\Users\username\source> $dir = ".\temp"
PS C:\Users\username\source> [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($dir)
C:\Users\username\temp
```

Now this:

```
PS C:\Users\username> cd source
PS C:\Users\username\source> powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\username\source> $dir = ".\temp"
PS C:\Users\username\source> [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($dir)
C:\Users\username\source\temp
```

Why does PowerShell interpret "." relative to the directory in which PowerShell was started, rather than the current directory? How can I get it to interpret "." relative to the current directory?

Comment: You can use `Get-Location`, `$PSScriptRoot` and `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` all depending on what you want. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343767/how-to-get-the-current-directory-of-the-cmdlet-being-executed

Comment: Use `Resolve-Path $dir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57776471/45375) states, it is the **use of a *.NET method* that introduces the problem**:
**.NET's *single, process-wide* current directory typically and by design<sup>[1]</sup> *differs* from PowerShell's *runspace-specific* one.**

This has the following implications:

- Since **PowerShell itself *does* reliably interpret `.` as the current *location*** (which is PowerShell's generalization of the concept of a current *directory* that can refer to other types of locations as well, on drives exposed by other PowerShell drive providers, such as the *registry* provider), you can **avoid the problem by using *PowerShell* commands**, if available.
- **When you do call .NET methods, be sure to *resolve any relative paths to absolute, file-system-native<sup>[2]</sup> ones* beforehand** or, where supported, additionally supply the current PowerShell filesystem location as a *reference* directory - this avoids the problem of the mismatched current directories.
- (Another, but suboptimal option is to first set `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD.ProviderPath` every time a relative path is passed, but that is clumsy and shouldn't be used if there's a chance that multiple PowerShell runspaces exist in the same process.)

The next section shows how to safely pass relative PowerShell paths to .NET methods, whereas the bottom section solves the specific problem in your question: how to resolve an arbitrary, given PowerShell path to an absolute, native filesystem path.

**Caveat**:

- For resolving *relative* paths, the solutions below assume that PowerShell's current location (as output by `Get-Location` / reflected in `$PWD`) is a *file-system* location, i.e. a *directory* - as is typical.
- If this assumption cannot be made (in the unlikely event that the current location is a *registry* location, for instance), an explicit reference to the `FileSystem` [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers)'s location is required, using `(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath` in lieu of `$PWD.ProviderPath` below. Notably, this precludes the `Convert-Path` and `New-Item` approaches below.

---

#### Passing a known *relative* file-system path safely to a .NET method:

As stated, the discrepancy in current directories requires that an *absolute* path be passed to .NET methods, arrived at based on *PowerShell*'s current directory.

The examples assume relative path `someFile.txt` to be passed to .NET method `[IO.File]::ReadAllText()` and `[IO.File]::WriteAllText()`

Note that simple string interpolation is used, with `/` (which can be used interchangeably with `\`) used to join the path components; if the current directory happens to be the *root* directory, you'll end up with *2* path separators, but that doesn't affect functionality. If you still need to avoid that, however, use the `Join-Path` cmdlet instead.

##### If the path is known to *exist*:

**Use `Convert-Path`**:

```bash
[IO.File]::ReadAllText((Convert-Path -LiteralPath someFile.txt))
```

That **[`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) and [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) only work with *existing* paths (as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2)** is unfortunate; providing an opt- in for nonexistent path has been proposed in [GitHub issue #2993](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2993).

Similarly, it would be helpful if `Convert-Path` and `Resolve-Path` supported a `-PSProvider` parameter to allow specifying the target provider explicitly, as `Get-Location` already supports - see [GitHub issue #10494](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10494).

##### If the path is one *to be created*:

The **simplest and robust approach** is to use [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) to let PowerShell create the item *beforehand*, which returns a file-system information object whose `.FullName` property reflects the full, native path:

```bash
# For a *directory* path, use -Type Directory
[IO.File]::WriteAllText(
  (New-Item -Type File ./someFile.txt).FullName,
  "sample content"
)
```

If you don't want to create the file/directory in PowerShell beforehand, there are several approaches:

- **Simplest, but not fully robust**, via`$PWD` (fails if the current directory is based on a *PowerShell-specific drive* created with `New-PsDrive` or if the current location is not a *filesystem* location):

```bash
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$PWD/someFile.txt", "sample content")
```

- **More robust**: via `$PWD.ProviderPath` (resolves a PowerShell drive-based path to the underlying native filesystem path, but can still fail if the current location is not a *filesystem* location):

```bash
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$($PWD.ProviderPath)/someFile.txt", "sample content")
```

- **Fully robust**: via `(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath`

```bash
[IO.File]::WriteAllText(
  "$((Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath)/someFile.txt"),
  "sample content"
)
```

---

#### Resolving *any given file-system path* to a full, native one:

That is, you may have to resolve to a full, file-system native a path that is *given* to you, which may or may not be relative, and may or may not be based on a PowerShell-specific drive (which .NET knows nothing about).

**If the path *exists*, use `Convert-Path`** to resolve any PowerShell filesystem path to an absolute, filesystem-native one:

```bash
$dir = "./temp"
Convert-Path -LiteralPath $dir
```

The related `Resolve-Path` cmdlet provides similar functionality, but it doesn't resolve paths based on *PowerShell-specific drives* (created with `New-PsDrive`) to their underlying native filesystem paths.

**If the path *doesn't exist* (yet)**:

Note:

- For brevity, `$PWD.ProviderPath` is used below to refer to the current file-system location's native path. As noted, this presumes that PowerShell's current location is indeed a *file-system* location, as is typical; for full robustness, use `(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath` instead.

**In PowerShell (Core) v6+**, which builds on .NET Core / .NET 5+, you can use the new **[`[IO.Path]::GetFullPath()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.GetFullPath)** overload that **accepts a *reference directory*** for the specified relative path:

```bash
$dir = "./temp"
[IO.Path]::GetFullPath($dir, $PWD.ProviderPath)
```

**In *Windows PowerShell***, you ***additionally* need [`[IO.Path]::Combine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.Combine)**:

Note: In the **simplest case**, i.e. if your relative paths never *start with* `\` (or `/`)<sup>[3]</sup> and you don't care about *normalizing* the resulting path (by resolving `.\` or `..\` components and/or having `/` normalized to `\`), `[IO.Path]::Combine()` *alone* is enough:

```bash
# !! Note the limitations.
$dir = "temp"
[IO.Path]::Combine($PWD.ProviderPath, $dir)
```

*Combining* `[IO.Path]::Combine()` with `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath()` overcomes these limitations:

```bash
# Robust solution
$dir = "./temp"
[IO.Path]::GetFullPath([IO.Path]::Combine($PWD.ProviderPath, $dir))
```

---

<sup>[1] While a given process typically has only *one* PowerShell runspace (session), the potential for *multiple* ones to coexist in a process means that it is conceptually impossible for all of them to sync their individual working directories with the one and only process-wide .NET working directory. For a more in-depth explanation, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428).</sup>

<sup>[2] That is, paths based on *PowerShell-specific drives* (see [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)) must be translated to paths based on drives known to *all* processes.</sup>

<sup>[3] As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) notes, `[IO.Path]::Combine()` considers a (non-UNC) path that starts with `\` (or `/`) a *full* one, despite being rooted only relative *to the current drive*. Therefore, such paths must be prefixed with the drive spec. of the native file-system directory underlying PowerShell's current location to form a truly full path.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a .net thing: [Why don't .NET objects in PowerShell use the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246068/why-dont-net-objects-in-powershell-use-the-current-directory)

A common workaround:

```
[xml]$xml = cat file.xml
$xml.save("$pwd\file.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell treats the `.` as the current location. So if you do `Get-ChildItem -Path ".\"`, this will return everything in the current directory. To get a relative path, you would need to do something like this:

```
Set-Location -Path "Path"
$path = Get-Item -Path "file" | Resolve-Path -Relative
```

`$path` would now be a relative path