# foreach with mutliple variables foreach($number) in Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, enumeration

I want to use multiple inputs in `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($numberin in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberin.txt") & ($numberout in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberout.txt")) 
{ ... }
```

But somehow "&" isn't working there.

like this

```
foreach($numberin in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberin.txt") -and ($numberout in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberout.txt"))
```

it tells me "unexpected token"

like this

```
foreach($numberin in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberin.txt") -and ($numberout in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberout.txt")
```

it tells me I need a closing ")" for the foreach

To clarify what I want to do:
I want to load some input from two files in two variables and do something with them each time it loads a new line from each file.

Comment: Those operators are only supported in Powershell 7. It would also be defined as `&&` you need to use `-and` here. I'd also suggest splitting the queries into variables rather than the separate command each time

Comment: ```foreach($numberin in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberin.txt") -and ($numberout in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberout.txt"))``` is not yet working, what should it look like in this example?

Comment: Why do you chain them like that? assign the [System.IO.. portion to a variable so $numberin in $x

Comment: @Isaac Just added more info what happens when I try to apply this.

Comment: What is your intent here?  It looks like you are trying to read numbers from numberin and numberout in parallel.  That is a rather weird format for your input data, but if you have no choice in the inputs, so be it.  It's also not clear what you are trying to do within the scope of the loop,  stuff that would be bracketed by {}.

Comment: I want to load some input from two files in two variables and do something with them each time it loads a new line from each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I wanted to do:

```
#Begin with first line in "numberout.txt"
$counter = 0

foreach ($numberin in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\numberin.txt")){
$numberout = (Get-Content file.txt)[$counter]
$counter = $counter +1
```

maybe someone can tell me how to replace my "Get-Content" with [System.IO.File] too.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, get-content accepts an array of input filenames.  It works without extra parentheses.  `&` is the call operator, and `-and` is a conditional operator.

```
foreach ($numberin in get-content numberin.txt,numberout.txt) { 
  $numberin 
}
```

Here's a more generic example of using `$( )` to combine the output of two commands:

```
foreach ($i in $(dir; get-date) ) { 
  $i 
}
```

Actually the `&&` operator works in powershell 7, as long as the first command is successful.  `||` would only use the first file.

```
foreach ($i in cat file1 && cat file2 ) { $i }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you describe what you are trying to accomplish. `&` is the call operator in Pwsh 7+ `&&` is a [pipeline chain operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators?view=powershell-7.1) that instructs PowerShell to run the right side only if the left side succeeds.  `-and` is a [logical operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.1) and judging by the code you did provide I don't think it does what you are intending.

If you are trying to combine the results of the 2 read operations you may think about simply reading them both. In Pwsh 7+ using the `&&` operator, might look something like:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines( 'C:\temp\test2.csv' ) && [System.IO.File]::ReadLines( 'C:\temp\test2.csv' ) |
ForEach-Object{ $_ }
```

In older versions you could do something like:

```
{
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines( 'C:\temp\test2.csv' )
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines( 'C:\temp\test2.csv' ) 
}.Invoke() |
ForEach-Object{ $_ }
```

You could send the file read output to 1 or more variables too.  Memory is rarely an issue so you can probably send the file read output to 1 or more variables. Might make the code easier to read and work with etc...

Easy enough to convert to `ForEach` keyword instead of `ForEach-Object`, but I wouldn't say more until the intent/desired result is clarified.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, load files with [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$a = Get-Content .\numberin.txt
```

---

By default, this will emit individual lines in a [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$a = Get-Content .\numberin.txt

$a | Select-Object -First 1
```

---

Load a second file.

```
$a = Get-Content .\numberin.txt
$b = Get-Content .\numberout.txt
```

---

You have not explained what you are doing with the file data.

Looking ahead, it is not necessary to create your own algorithm for comparing files. You can use [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1).

Pay careful attention to the `Compare-Object` parameters as these options might solve some of your problems.

```
$a = get-content .\a.out
$b = get-content .\b.out

Compare-Object $a $b

# output 

InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
sapien. Quisque ac lectus sit amet lectus ornare mattis.    =>
Etiam ut placerat purus. Aliquam at hendrerit purus, ac     =>
iaculis risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean eu  =>
potenti. Pellentesque felis ligula, dignissim vel neque     <=
commodo, fermentum pharetra neque. Sed placerat a metus nec <=
tincidunt. Sed massa quam, viverra non viverra eget,        <=
```

---

Note that `SideIndicator` is a normal, object property. It can be used in filters.

```
$a = get-content .\a.out
$b = get-content .\b.out

Compare-Object $a $b | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } 

# output 

InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
potenti. Pellentesque felis ligula, dignissim vel neque     <=
commodo, fermentum pharetra neque. Sed placerat a metus nec <=
tincidunt. Sed massa quam, viverra non viverra eget,        <=
```

---

Alternatively, you can append the files in memory.

```
$a = get-content .\a.out
$b = get-content .\b.out

$a, $b
```

---

Or save the result to disc.

```
$a = get-content .\a.out
$b = get-content .\b.out

$a, $b | Set-Content .\c.out
```

---

See Also

- [How to Compare files in Visual Studio Code ? - Daily .NET Tips](https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-compare-files-in-visual-studio-code/)
- [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell's [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement does *not* support *multiple* iteration variables.**

- Adding such support was proposed in [GitHub issue #14732](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732), but was unfortunately decided against.
- *If* support had been implemented, your command would have looked like this:

  ```bash
  # WAS NEVER IMPLEMENTED
  foreach($numberin, $numberOut in 
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path numberin.txt)),
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path numberout.txt))
  ) { ... }
  ```

The **closest you can get** is the following approach, which uses the `.GetEnumerator()` method to obtain [*enumerator objects*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator), and explicitly enumerates them in tandem inside a `while` loop:

```bash
# Obtain enumerators for both files.
$numberInEnum, $numberOutEnum = 
  [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path numberin.txt)).GetEnumerator(),
  [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path numberout.txt)).GetEnumerator()

# Manually enumerate them with .MoveNext() for as long as one file still 
# has input lines left and obtain the current value (line) via .Current:
while ($numberInEnum.MoveNext(), $numberOutEnum.MoveNext() -contains $true) {
  $numberIn, $numberOut = $numberInEnum.Current, $numberOutEnum.Current
  "[$numberIn] vs. [$numberOut]"  # sample output
}
```

**Important**:

- Note the use of [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path), which ensures that a *full path* is passed to the .NET method calls, which is important, because *.NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375) for background.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `&` is *`cmd.exe`'s* statement separator: it allows putting multiple statements on a single line; PowerShell's equivalent is `;`

  - [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now supports `&&` and `||` for *conditional* sequencing of multiple statements.
- `-and`, as a *logical* operator, works fundamentally differently: it coerces both operands to *Booleans* (and consumes their output in the process) and returns a single Boolean: `$true` if both coerced-to-Boolean operands evaluated to `$true`, `$false` otherwise.
- None of these can solve your problem.