# Can't remove directory passed as argument to the powershell script runs asynchronously

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which needs to delete the directory passed as argument and the script should be started asynchronously.

Example:
Script_1.ps1

`$Path = "C:\XYZ"`

`$tempDir = "C:\Temp"`

`Start-Process  -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "$($tempDir)\Script_2.ps1","-PathToDelete","$Path"`

Script_2.ps1

```
param(
# The path to delete
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$False,HelpMessage="The path to delete")]
[string]$PathToDelete,
)

Remove-Item -path $PathToDelete -Recurse -Force 

exit 0
```

Currently ,Remove_Item throws exception saying path cannot deleted because it's in use. Process explorer says the path to be deleted is used by powershell process started in script_1.ps.

Answer (score 3):

You say that the process running `Script_1.ps1` is preventing the removal, and **I'm assuming you've already *ruled out* the following causes**:

- You're running that script from a directory located inside the directory tree you're trying to remove.
- Inside that script, before calling `Script_2.ps1`:

  - you're changing the current directory to a directory located inside the directory tree.
  - or you've opened a file located in that directory tree without having closed it yet.

This leaves the following potential - and obscure - cause:

**The *process-level working directory* - which is distinct from PowerShell's current location - may be a directory inside the directory tree you're trying to remove**, thereby preventing removal.

To rule that out, change it to `C:\` from inside `Script_2.ps1`, before calling [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item), as follows:

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = 'C:\'
```

Note:

- That PowerShell's working directory (as reflected in the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) and the return value from [`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location)) differs from the process' is unfortunate, but cannot be avoided, because a single PowerShell process can host multiple runspaces (sessions) simultaneously, each of which must maintain their own working directory (location) - see [GitHub issue #3428](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428).
- A more common pitfall that results from this discrepancy is owed to the fact that *.NET APIs use the process' working directory*, which means that you cannot pass *relative paths* to .NET methods without risking their resolution relative to a *different* working directory than PowerShell's - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375) for more information.