# PowerShell - Best practice working with files

Tags: powershell

For reasons I'm starting to regret, I got into the habit of just working with `[System.IO.FileInfo]` and now I'm wondering if there is a best practice around avoiding that and just using full names to the file(s) or if there is a different workaround for my current conundrum.

I need to make a lot of my smaller scripts work with `powershell.exe` vs. `pwsh.exe` because they're going to be used by folks and computers that don't have PowerShell (Core) installed - but every once in a while there arises an issue. This time it is the handling of whatever is returned from `Get-ChildItem` and the fact that Windows PowerShell doesn't give you the full path like PowerShell (Core) does. One workaround I have would be to force the full name (`$file.FullName`), but that in turn breaks the fact that I'm accustomed to working with `System.IO.FileInfo` variables.

So first question without examples: **What is the best practice? Should I have been using `System.IO.FileInfo` in the first place?**

Second question, with examples: Is there a better way to handle this so that Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) act consistently?

Consider the following - at this point I would probably call a function to act on each qualifying input file (using filtering on name or file extension, etc. to get the right set).

```
PS C:\tmp> Function CustomFunction{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[System.IO.FileInfo]$inputFile
)
$inputFile.BaseName
$inputFile.DirectoryName
$inputFile.GetType()
"`n`n"
}
PS C:\tmp> (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PWD -File).ForEach({CustomFunction $_})
```

In PowerShell (Core) - The type `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` and the function would work even if the file itself isn't located in the working directory

```
Another File
C:\tmp

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

Windows PowerShell is still using a type of `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` - but there is definitely something different between them. I'm not sure what "IsSerial" actually checks, but if `CustomFunction` were taking action on the files then it won't work if they're not in the working directory.

```
Another File
C:\tmp

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

So - what's my best course of action? I like the `FileInfo` objects themselves because they have some handy properties like `BaseName`, `Directory`, `DirectoryName`, and `Extension`. There are probably also a number of useful methods available that I might be using in my functions.

If I just essentially pass `$_.FullName` to the function, then within the function it is a string and I'll need to use `Split-Path` among other things to get similar properties that I'm working with

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [***inconsistent* stringification** of `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances **in *Windows PowerShell***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) is unfortunate - sometimes by file *name* only, other times by *full path* (everything in this answer applies analogously to [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances) - this has since been ***fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+*** (via an underlying .NET API change), where such instances now *consistently* stringify to their *full* path.

To **make code work robustly in *both* PowerShell editions**, two fundamental **scenarios** apply:

- Passing `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances to *other file-processing cmdlets*, in which case you can provide them *as pipeline input* - see the next section.
- Passing them to *external programs* and *.NET methods*, in which case their `.FullName` property must be used - see the bottom section.

---

When you need to **pass [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) / [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) to *other file-processing cmdlets***, namely cmdlets that have pipeline-binding `-LiteralPath` parameters, such as `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`  you can stick with `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances and **provide them *as pipeline input*** ; e.g.:

```bash
# Robust alternative to the following *brittle* commands:
#    Get-ChildItem $someFileInfoInstance  # -Path implied
#    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $someFileInfoInstance
# Same as: 
#    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $someFileInfoInstance.PSPath
$someFileInfoInstance | Get-ChildItem
```

A [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) bound this way - assuming that it wasn't constructed *directly* - binds via its PowerShell provider-supplied `.PSPath` property value, which is *always* its full path, even in Windows PowerShell.
The reason that it is the `.PSPath` property value that binds is that `-PSPath` is defined as an *alias* of the `-LiteralPath` parameter, combined with declaring the latter as [`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute.ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName).

Note:

- **Generally, all standard cmdlets that have a `-LiteralPath` parameter support this mechanism**.

  - See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922416/45375) for how to infer whether the mechanism is supported by a given cmdlet by examining its parameter definitions.
- **An unfortunate exception *due to its buggy implementation in Windows PowerShell* is `Import-Csv`** - again, this has since been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+.
- As an aside: The problem generally wouldn't exist if passing a pipeline-binding parameter's value *as an argument* exhibited the same behavior as *via the pipeline* - see [GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057).

  - That is, you would expect `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $someFileInfoInstance` to bind the parameter, which is *string*-typed, in the same way as `$someFileInfoInstance | Get-ChildItem`.
  - However, that is *not* the case: when passed *as an argument*, *simple `.ToString()` stringification* is performed, which in combination with Windows PowerShell's *inconsistent* stringification of `System.IO.FileInfo` instances causes *situational* malfunctioning.

Alternatively, you can always *explicitly* use the `.PSPath` property value to predictably get a *full* path, but that is both more verbose and error-prone (easy to forget).

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $someFileInfoInstance.PSPath
```

Note that `.PSPath` values are prefixed by the name of the [PowerShell provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) underlying the item at hand, such as `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` for file-system items.

As such, `.PSPath` isn't suitable for passing for passing file-system paths to *external programs* or *.NET methods*, which are discussed next.

---

**Passing file-system paths to *external programs* and *.NET methods*:**

In these cases, a *full, file-system-native path* must be passed.

- External programs and .NET methods are unaware of PowerShell-only drives (those established with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)), so any paths based on them wouldn't be recognized (and neither would PowerShell paths referring to *non*-file-system items, such as registry keys based on PowerShell's `HKLM:` drive).
- In the case of external programs, a *relative* file-system path would work too, but .NET methods require a *full* path, due to .NET's working directory usually differing from PowerShell's (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375)).

To ensure use of a full, file-system-native path:

- For **`[System.IO.FileInfo]` / `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances**, use their **`.FullName` property**.

  - As stated above, this is no longer necessary in PowerShell (Core) v6.1+, where such instances *consistently* stringify to their `.FullName` property values. (Stringification happens invariably when passing arguments to external programs, and when passing arguments to `string`-typed (file-path) parameters of .NET methods).
- For **`[System.Management.Automation.PathInfo]` instances**, such as returned by [`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location) and reflected in the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) variable, use their **`.ProviderPath` property**.

Examples:

```bash
cmd /c echo (Get-Item .).FullName
cmd /c echo $PWD.ProviderPath
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a [lengthy discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7132) about this when the change was made to default ToString to result in a full path instead of a relative path.

### TL;DR

[Steve Lee stated](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7132#issuecomment-503773204) the best practice is to explicitly declare whether you want the full path or the relative path by using `$_.Name` or `$_.Fullname`.

#### Bad Practice ❌

```
$fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $MyFilePath
Write-Host "My file is: $fileInfo"
```

#### Best Practice ✅

```
$fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $MyFilePath
Write-Host "My file is: $($fileInfo.FullName)"
```

### Details

`Get-ChildItem` returns a `System.IO.FileInfo` object in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core. The problem you're encountering is with the implementation of the `ToString` method of the `System.IO.FileInfo` object.

You type and run this:

```
$fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $MyFilePath
Write-Host "My file is: $fileInfo"
```

...which gets translated into this:

```
$fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $MyFilePath
Write-Host "My file is: $(fileInfo.ToString())"
```

..which gets translated to this on Windows PowerShell:

```
$fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $MyFilePath
Write-Host "My file is: $(fileInfo.Name)"
```

...and this on PowerShell Core:

```
$fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $MyFilePath
Write-Host "My file is: $(fileInfo.FullName)"
```

The reason they moved from using `.Name` to `.FullName` for the default implementation of ToString appears to be something related to security because relative paths could be tinkered with.

The reason it's a best practice to explicitly convert objects into strings instead of relying on the object to figure out how to convert itself into a string is because of exactly this scenario, the implementation could change and leave you up a creek.

Comment: (a) It is worth clarifying that your best practice is only worth heeding if your code must _also_ still run in the legacy _Windows PowerShell_ edition. (b) Stringifying `$fileInfo` isn't _always_  the same as `$fileInfo.Name` - sometimes it _is_ `$fileInfo.FullName`, which is what makes stringifying `FileInfo` / `DirectoryInfo` instances so treacherous - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) summarizes when you get one vs. the other.

Comment: As an aside: I suggest not using `Write-Host` in sample code, as it might mislead beginners to think that (a) using a cmdlet is necessary to produce output in PowerShell (it isn't) and that (b) the cmdlet to use for producing output is `Write-Host` (it generally isn't, unless your intent is to _write directly to the screen_ (host) rather than to _output data_).

Comment: Probably shouldn't have used `Write-Host`, but it helped me narrow down the issue a bit. To make sure I understand my own problem correctly though, I don't believe I'm trying to or want to convert the object to string anyway. My code is actually more like this: `(gci -LiteralPath $Path -Filter '*.csv' -File).ForEach({CustomFunction $_})`. The first parameter of `CustomFunction` is `param([System.IO.FileInfo]$inputFile)` which is also mandatory. In essence though, I think I'm expecting to receive the object and maybe I haven't been this entire time, but I thought I was

Comment: That scenario should be fine @immobile2. You'd get weirdness if your param looked like this though: `param([string]$inputFileName)` since that effectively calls `toString` as well which is when you run into the problems you were asking about.

Comment: The point about not relying on implicit stringification is a good one in general, though in this case there definitely won't be further changes. Consistently and therefore _predictably_ 
stringifying to the _full_ path is what .NET Framework (Windows PowerShell) should arguably always have done too.

Comment: But the larger issue here is PowerShell's parameter binding:
There _is_ a predictable mechanism that doesn't rely on stringification and so also works robustly in WinPS: passing `FileInfo` instances _as pipeline input_,
where the provider-supplied `.PSPath` property value is bound to `-LiteralPath`, which is guaranteed to be a full path.
Unfortunately - and surprisingly - this only works _via the pipeline_, and not when passing such an instance _as an argument_, which is an awkward general asymmetry 
discussed in [GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057).

Comment: Thanks for the links and help, I feel dumb now because the issue wasn't the `FileInfo` object at all...it was the fact I was using `Import-Csv` and lazily passing `$inputFile` which got stringified as you mention.