# Get-FileHash piped from Resolve-Path not working as expected

Tags: powershell

What am I missing here?
This command works as expected:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\subdir\ -Recurse -Filter *.* | Resolve-Path -Relative
```

and so does this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\subdir\ -Recurse -Filter *.* | Resolve-Path -Relative | Sort
```

But the following one fails:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\subdir\ -Recurse -Filter *.* | Resolve-Path -Relative | Get-FileHash
```

Edit: What I am trying to achieve is to get relative path of files in the final output.

Thanks in advance!

==Edit#2==

I came up with this following google:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^*.exe|^*.dll' } 

$output = foreach ($f in $files)
{
  "" | Select-Object @{
         Name='FileName';
         Expression={(Resolve-Path -Relative $f.FullName)}
       },

       @{
          Name='SHA1';
          Expression={(Get-FileHash $f.FullName -Algorithm SHA1).Hash}
       }
} 

echo $output
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: `"" | Select-Object @{ ... }` is a strange and cumbersome way to create an object. Much clearer way: `[PSCustomObject]@{ FileName = Resolve-Path -Relative $f.FullName; SHA1 = (Get-FileHash $f.FullName -Algorithm SHA1).Hash }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This answer addresses your question *as originally asked*. For the solution to your *actual* question, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69930620/45375).

---

- **Don't use `-Filter *.*` if your true intent is to match *files only*** - files can *lack* an extension (e.g. `file`) and, conversely, directories may *have* one (e.g. `dir.foo`)

  - Instead, use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s **`-File` switch**.
- Don't use [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) `-RelativePath` if your intent is to pipe file-information objects to [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash).

  - Instead, **pipe the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem` *directly* to `Get-FileHash`**.

Therefore, use the following:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\subdir\ -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash
```

Your intermediate **`Resolve-Path -Relative` call** *does* work in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* - but *not* in *Windows PowerShell* - but either way ***there is no benefit to using it***, because **the `.Path` property of the objects *output* by `Get-FileHash` *always* contain the *full* path**, irrespective of whether the *input* path was relative or not.
Again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69930620/45375) for how to get relative paths in the desired *output* objects.

---

To put it differently:

- Piping a - relative or absolute - path *as a string* to `Get-FileHash` *should* work, but - due to a limitation in *Windows PowerShell* - doesn't (fixed in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*).
- In general, **the following *should* apply to *all* file-processing cmdlets**, which have both a `-Path` and a `-LiteralPath` parameter (the former potentially accepting *wildcard expressions*, the latter accepting *literal* (verbatim) paths only):

  - They **accept *string* input via the pipeline**, which **binds to the `-Path` parameter** (via that parameter's `ValueFromPipeline` property)

    - Notably, this means that path strings are interpreted as [*wildcard* expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), not as literal paths.
  - They **accept `System.IO.FileInfo` / `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` input via the pipeline** - as output by `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`, for instance - which **binds to the `-LiteralPath` parameter** (via that parameter's `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` property, which binds to the input objects' `.PSPath` property, by virtue of `-PSPath` being a declared *alias* for `-LiteralPath`)

As an aside: Perhaps surprisingly, the pipeline-binding rules are *not* also applied to passing a
`-LiteralPath` value *as a direct argument* rather than via the pipeline - see [GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057)

---

To **inspect the pipeline-relevant properties of the `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` parameters of a given cmdlet**:

If you don't also need to see the *alias* names of these parameters,<sup>[1]</sup> only the pipeline-binding behavior with respect to their *primary* names,  the solution is simple:

```sh
& { Get-Help $args[0] -Parameter *Path } Get-FileHash
```

If you *do* want to see the parameter alias names, it gets a bit more complicated, unfortunately (note how `Get-FileHash` is passed as an *argument* to the script block (`{ ... }` being invoked; you may pass any cmdlet name of interest):

```sh
& {
  (Get-Command $args[0]).ParameterSets.Parameters | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*Path' } |
    Select-Object Name, Aliases, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterType
} Get-FileHash | Format-Table
```

*Windows PowerShell* output:

```sh
Name        Aliases  ValueFromPipeline ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName ParameterType  
----        -------  ----------------- ------------------------------- -------------  
Path        {}                   False                           False System.String[]
LiteralPath {PSPath}             False                            True System.String[]
```

*PowerShell (Core) 7+* output:

```sh
Name        Aliases      ValueFromPipeline ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName ParameterType
----        -------      ----------------- ------------------------------- -------------
Path        {}                        True                            True System.String[]
LiteralPath {PSPath, LP}             False                            True System.String[]
```

The above shows that `Get-FileHash`:

- In *Windows PowerShell*:

  - accepts *no* direct *string* input via the pipeline (*no* `ValueFromPipeline` property value set to `$true`).
  - only binds *objects* that have a *`.PSPath` property* to `-LiteralPath` (i.e., objects output by `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`), due to `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` being `$true`, by that property's value.
- In *PowerShell Core 7+*:

  - *does* accept direct string input, via the `-Path` parameter, and also via input objects that have a `.Path` property.
  - as in Windows PowerShell, binds objects that have a `.PSPath` property to `-LiteralPath` by that property's value, and, additionally, analogously objects with a `.LP` property, which is implied by the fact that in PowerShell (Core) `-LP` is now an official alias of `-LiteralPath`.

---

<sup>[1] It is unfortunate that [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) `-Parameter` output doesn't list aliases - see [GitHub issue #13418](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13418). A related problem is that you cannot request parameter information *via* an alias - see [GitHub issue #6183](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6183).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, in powershell 5.1, only literalpath or its alias pspath can be piped to get-filehash.  And apparently also only by property name, not by value, which doesn't seem to appear in the docs anymore.  Your code would work ok in powershell 7.

```
[pscustomobject]@{literalpath='there'} | get-filehash

Algorithm Hash                                                Path
--------- ----                                                ----
SHA256    73253E1BB32AE0BE82342FA1CEA0A653CC84097CD65D6DE9... C:\users\js\foo\there
```

Or since the pspath property can be piped:

```
get-childitem there | get-filehash
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**:

- This question is an example of the XY problem - asking for help with the *perceived solution* to a problem instead of (also) stating *the problem itself*.
- The **true intent**, stated as such only after answers were given, was to **create file-hash objects containing *relative paths***.
- See the **bottom section** for efficient **solutions**.

---

Your question turned out to be a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777):

- Your real, originally unstated goal was to create objects that represent files by their cryptographic hash string, obtained with [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash), and *relative paths*; relative to the starting directory of the recursion via `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`, that is.
- To that end, you tried to pipe the output from [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) `-Relative` to `Get-FileHash` under the - mistaken - *assumption* that doing so would result in output objects whose `.Path` property reflects the *relative* input path.

  - In reality, that property *always* contains a *full* path.

When your command *failed altogether* - in *Windows PowerShell* - you made your question *about that failure*, instead of formulating your actual goal.

As a result, you received answers matching the question *as asked*:

- [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922348/45375) explains the *technical* reason for the failure in *Windows PowerShell* and notes that it *technically* works in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*
- [My original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922416/45375) dives deeper into the *technical* problems, while also pointing out that the problem you tried to solve - getting `Resolve-Path -RelativePath` input to work with `Get-FileHash` - *wasn't worth solving*:

  - In Windows PowerShell, simply *omitting* `Resolve-Path -RelativePath` would have made your command work (albeit, as stated, invariably with *full* paths)
  - In PowerShell (Core) 7+, the `Resolve-Path -RelativePath` call amounts to an unnecessary no-op.

You later changed the premise of your question to reveal your true intent, and even edited an *answer* into it - both actions are ill-advised:

- By changing the premise of your question later, you're invalidating previously given answers: these answers don't match the question any longer and are likely to cause confusion for future readers.
- Solutions belong into *answer posts*, for a clear separation between a question and its answer. As an answer, it can also be *accepted*, which is an important signal to future readers as to what solution actually worked.

---

A **solution** that improves on your own attempt and **works in *both* PowerShell editions**:

```sh
# Get the full path of the start dir, using the current dir. as an example.
$startDir = Convert-Path -LiteralPath '.'

# Determine the length of the start dir's path prefix, which,
# when removed from the full paths of the files found during the enumeration,
# yields the relative paths.
$startDirPrefixLen = $startDir.Length + (1, 0)[$startDir[-1] -in '\', '/']

# Walk the start dir's subtree recursively and, for each file of interest,
# output an object with the relative path and the file's hash.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $startDir -File -Recurse -Include *.exe, *.dll |
  ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      FileName = $_.FullName.Substring($startDirPrefixLen)
      SHA1 = ($_ | Get-FileHash).Hash
    }
  }
```

**A more convenient *PowerShell (Core) 7+* solution**, via the new [`[System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.GetRelativePath) .NET API method:

```sh
# Get the full path of the start dir, using the current dir. as an example.
# Note: While [IO.Path]::GetRelativePath() itself supports relative input
#       paths, they wouldn't be resolved correctly, because .NET's
#       working directory typically differs from PowerShell's`.
$startDir = Convert-Path -LiteralPath '.'

# Walk the start dir's subtree recursively and, for each file of interest,
# output an object with the relative path and the file's hash.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $startDir -File -Recurse -Include *.exe, *.dll |
  ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      FileName = [IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($startDir, $_.FullName)
      SHA1 = ($_ | Get-FileHash).Hash
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear to begin with. I am fairly new to PowerShell. Intention was to learn enough to come up with my own solution, rather than asking for a free solution.

Comment: That is commendable, @ssh. The answers here now provide _both_: an explanation of where your original approach fell short _and_ an improved version of your later, amended solution attempt, after the XY problem became apparent - which you should never have edited into your _question_. To guide future readers, however, you should accept the answer that provides the best solution to your (later revealed as such) problem.