# unable to read contents of file

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to read the contents of a file:

```
$releaseNotesPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_ccp-develop\ccp\ccp\ReleaseNotes\ReleaseNotes\"
$latestReleaseNotesFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $releaseNotesPath -Filter *.txt | Select-Object FullName,Name | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -First 1
```

The issue occurs here:

```
$releaseNote = Get-Content $latestReleaseNotesFile


2021-11-14T14:29:07.0729088Z ##[error]Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{FullName=D' does not exist.
2021-11-14T14:29:07.1945879Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the file path (`FullName`):

```
$releaseNote = Get-Content $latestReleaseNotesFile.FullName
```

Answer (score 2):

Shayki Abramczyk already answered how, I'll chime in with the *why* part.

So, let's see what goes on, step by step

```
# Assign a value to variable, simple enough
$latestReleaseNotesFile = 
# Get a list of all 
Get-ChildItem -Path $releaseNotesPath -Filter *.txt | 
# Interested only on file full name and shortname. Here's the catch
Select-Object FullName,Name | 
# Sort the results by name
Sort-Object -Property Name | 
# Return the first object of collection.
Select-Object -First 1
```

Note that in the catch part, you are implicitly creating a new, custom Powershell object that contains two members: a fully qualified file name and short name. When you pass the custom object later to `Get-Content`, it doesn't know how to process the custom object. So, thus the error. Shayki's answer works, as it explicitly tells to use the `FullName` member that contains, well file's full name.

Answer (score 2):

There's good information in the existing answers; let me summarize and complement them:

A simplified and robust reformulation of your command:

```sh
$latestReleaseNotesFile = 
  Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $releaseNotesPath -Filter *.txt | 
    Select-Object -First 1

$releaseNote = $latestReleaseNotesFile | Get-Content
```

---

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) `-LiteralPath` parameter ensures that its argument is treated literally (verbatim), as opposed to as a *wildcard expression*, which is what `-Path` expects.
- `Get-ChildItem`'s output *is already sorted by name* (while this fact isn't officially documented, it is behavior that users have come to rely on, and it won't change).
- By *not* using [`Select-Object FullName, Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to transform the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem` to create `[pscustomobject]` instances with only the specified properties, the resulting object can *as a whole* be piped to `Get-Content`, where it is **implicitly bound by its `.PSPath` property value to `-LiteralPath`** (whose alias is `-PSPath`), which contains the full path (with a PowerShell [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) prefix).

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922416/45375) for details on how this pipeline-based binding works.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Get-Content $latestReleaseNotesFile`

This *positionally* binds the value of variable `$latestReleaseNotesFile` to the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Path` parameter.

Since `-Path` is `[string[]]`-typed (i.e., it accepts one or more *strings*; use `Get-Help Get-Content` to see that), `$latestReleaseNotesFile`'s value is *stringified* via its `.ToString()` method, if necessary.

> `Select-Object FullName, Name`

This creates `[pscustomobject]` instances with with `.FullName` and `.Name` properties, whose values are taken from the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem`.

Stringifying a `[pscustomobject]` instance yields an *informal*, hashtable-*like* representation suitable only for the human observer; e.g.:

```sh
# -> '@{FullName=/path/to/foo; Name=foo})'
"$([pscustomobject] @{ FullName = '/path/to/foo'; Name = 'foo' }))"
```

<sup>Note: I'm using an *expandable string* (`"..."`) to stringify, because calling `.ToString()` directly unexpectedly yields the *empty string*, due to a longstanding bug described in [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).</sup>

Unsurprisingly, passing a string with content `@{FullName=/path/to/foo; Name=foo})` is not a valid file-system path, and resulted in the error you saw.

Passing the `.FullName` property value instead, as shown in Shayki's answer, solves that problem:

- For full robustness, it is preferable to use `-LiteralPath` instead of the (positionally implied) `-Path`
- Specifically, paths that contain verbatim `[` or `]` will otherwise be misinterpreted as a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).

```sh
Get-Content -LiteralPath $latestReleaseNotesFile.FullName
```

As shown at the top, sticking with `System.IO.FileInfo` instances and providing them *via the pipeline* implicitly binds robustly to `-LiteralPath`:

```sh
# Assumes that $latestReleaseNotesFile is of type [System.IO.FileInfo]
# This is the equivalent of:
#   Get-Content -LiteralPath $latestReleaseNotesFile.PSPath
$latestReleaseNotesFile | Get-Content
```

**Pitfall**: One would therefore expect that passing the same type of object *as an argument* results in the *same* binding, but that is *not* true:

```sh
# !! NOT the same as:
#    $latestReleaseNotesFile | Get-Content
# !! Instead, it is the same as:
#    Get-Content -Path $latestReleaseNotesFile.ToString()
Get-Content $latestReleaseNotesFile
```

- That is, the argument is *not* bound by its `.PSPath` property value to `-LiteralPath`; instead, the *stringified value* is bound to `-Path`.
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, this is typically *not* a problem, because `System.IO.FileInfo` (and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`) instances *consistently* stringify to their *full* path (`.FullName` property value) - however, it still malfunctions for literal paths containing `[` or `]`.
- In *Windows PowerShell*, such instances *situationally* stringify to the file *name* (`.Name`) only, making *malfunctioning and subtle bugs likely* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).

This **problematic asymmetry** is discussed in [GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057).

The following is a summary of the above with concrete guidance:

---

##### Robustly passing file-system paths to file-processing cmdlets:

Note: The following applies not just to [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), but to *all* file-processing standard cmdlets - with the unfortunate exception of [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) in *Windows PowerShell*, due to a *bug*.

- **as an *argument***:

  - Use **`-LiteralPath`** explicitly, because using `-Path` (which is also implied if *neither* parameter is named) interprets its argument as a [*wildcard expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), which notably causes literal file paths containing `[` or `]` to be misinterpreted.

    ```sh
    # $pathString is assumed to be a string ([string])

    # OK: -LiteralPath ensures interpretation as a literal path.
    Get-Content -LiteralPath $pathString

    # Same as:
    #   Get-Content -Path $pathString
    # !! Path is treated as a *wildcard expression*.
    # !! This will often not matter, but breaks with paths with [ or ]
    Get-Content $pathString
    ```
  - *Additionally*, in **Windows PowerShell**, when passing a `System.IO.FileInfo` or `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instance, **explicitly use the `.FullName`** (file-system-native path) or **`.PSPath`** property (includes a PowerShell [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) prefix; path may be based on a [PowerShell-specific drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)) to ensure that its *full* path is used; this is no longer required in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where such instances *consistently* stringify to their `.FullName` property - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).

    ```sh
    # $fileSysInfo is assumed to be of type 
    # [System.IO.FileInfo] or [System.IO.DirectoryInfo].

    # Required for robustness in *Windows PowerShell*, works in both editions.
    Get-Content -LiteralPath $fileSysInfo.FullName

    # Sufficient in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*:
    Get-Content -LiteralPath $fileSysInfo
    ```
- **via the *pipeline***:

  - `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instances, such as emitted by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item), can be passed as a whole, and robustly bind to `-LiteralPath` via their `.PSPath` property values - in *both* PowerShell editions, so **you can safely use this approach in *cross-edition* scripts**.

    ```sh
    # Same as:
    #   Get-Content -LiteralPath $fileSysInfo.PSPath
    $fileSysInfo | Get-Content
    ```
  - This mechanism - explained in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922416/45375) - relies on a *property name* matching a *parameter name*, including the parameter's *alias* names. Therefore, input objects of *any* type that have either a `.LiteralPath`, a `.PSPath`, or, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* only, a `.LP` property (all alias names of the `-LiteralPath` parameter) are bound by that property's value.<sup>[1]</sup>

    ```sh
    # Same as:
    #   Get-Content -LiteralPath C:\Windows\win.ini
    [pscustomobject] @{ LiteralPath = 'C:\Windows\win.ini' } | Get-Content
    ```
  - By contrast, any object with a `.Path` property binds to the wildcard-supporting *`-Path`* parameter by that property's value.

    ```sh
    # Same as:
    #   Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\win.ini
    # !! Path is treated as a *wildcard expression*.
    [pscustomobject] @{ Path = 'C:\Windows\win.ini' } | Get-ChildItem
    ```
  - *Direct string input* and the stringified representations of any other objects also bind to `-Path`.

    ```sh
    # Same as:
    #   Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\win.ini
    # !! Path is treated as a *wildcard expression*.
    'C:\Windows\win.ini' | Get-Content
    ```

    - *Pitfall*: Therefore, feeding the lines of a text file via `Get-Content` to `Get-ChildItem`, for instance, can also malfunction with paths containing `[` or `]`. A simple workaround is to pass them *as an argument* to `-LiteralPath`:

      ```sh
      Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Get-Content -LiteralPath Paths.txt)
      ```

---

<sup>[1] That this logic is only applied to *pipeline input*, and not also to input to the same parameter *by argument* is an unfortunate asymmetry discussed in [GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057).</sup>