# Use Powershell to delete ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I am currently very annoyed by Dropbox and Nextcloud, which both battle the ShellIconOverlayIdentifier list. A problem which many people seem to have, when you search the internet.

Now I want to combine my annoyance with my intent to learn powershell (7.2.0).

I started with the following script, which shall retrieve all keys. And later I want to use regex via `-match` to find the entries I want to delete. For now I work with both `Remove-Item -WhatIf` and `Get-ItemProperty` to test it.

Currently my problem is that I can create my list as intended. But when I feed the list into the remove command I get that the path cannot be found. What am I doing wrong?

```
Push-Location -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers

$list = Get-ChildItem -Path .

$filteredList = $list -match "DropboxExt10"

$filteredList

# Remove-Item -WhatIf -Recurse $filteredList
Get-ItemProperty $filteredList

Pop-Location
```

The error is `Cannot find path 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\  DropboxExt10' because it does not exist.` Apparantly it adds the path as relative path to the current location. Why doesn't it interpret as an absolute path? When I ommit the push-location part it trys to add the registry path to my current working directory in which the script lives. But this is wrong as well.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the following:

```
$filteredList | Remove-Item -WhatIf -Recurse

# Alternatively:
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $filteredList.PSPath -WhatIf -Recurse
```

The above commands ensure that the registry items (keys) are bound by their *full, provider-qualified paths* to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)'s `-LiteralPath` parameter, via their `.PSPath` property; in the case of *registry paths*, the path's provider prefix is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::` (or, if identifying the originating *module* isn't also required, `Registry::`, as used in your `Push-Location` call)

What appears to be happening is that when the items are *stringified* - which is what happens when you pass them *as a whole*, *as an argument* (e.g. `Remove-Item $filteredlist`, which is the same as `Remove-Item -Path $filteredlist`), they *lack the provider prefix* and are represented as *registry-native paths*.

And given that a full registry-native path such as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...` neither starts with a *drive specification* nor with `\` or `/`, it is interpreted as a *relative* path, resulting in the symptom you saw.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation. Both variants work. Actually I came up with a third solution. Could you add it to your answer, so we have all options here? `foreach ($item in $filteredList) {Remove-Item -WhatIf -Recurse Registry::$item}`. Actually I was starting to like Powershell. But given that my version did not work, but your first proposed solution does, makes me wonder.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, Gunter; I'm glad the explanation was helpful. Honestly, given that the solutions in the answer are more concise (no loop) and faster than a `foreach`-loop solution, I don't think the latter is worth adding. Yes, it's not obvious why `$filteredList | Remove-Item -WhatIf -Recurse` works (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922416/45375)), and the quirks around passing paths can be frustrating. But, despite all its warts, PowerShell has a lot to offer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional link. I see I have to learn quite a bit to understand how Powershell cmdlets are actually processing information. And also thanks for pointing out that the loop solution would actually be slower. Indeed, Powershell has a lot to offer. I currently really like it for automating stuff, which took quite a few clicks otherwise (restarting services, deleting registry entries, restarting explorer.exe). So I expect a love-hate-relationship with powershell for now :-)