# PowerShell script that accepts pipeline input?

Tags: powershell, syntax, pipeline

Need a little help to tweak this script that copies the latest file to another folder:

```
$FilePath        = "C:\Downloads\Sales 202112*.xlsx"
$DestinationPath = "C:\myFiles\"

gci -Path $FilePath -File | 
  Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    Select FullName -First 1 |
      Copy-Item $_ -Destination $DestinationPath
```

Not sure how to reference pipeline input for the Copy-Item command.

Thanks.

Comment: what is exactly the problem? What is not working as you expect it?

Comment: Remove `FullName` and `$_` - `Copy-Item` _implicitly_ binds the pipeline input (`$_` is only needed in script blocks).

Comment: If I remove the last part beginning with "| Copy-Item", I get the last file name that I am interested in. However the Copy-Item item command does not work.

Comment: @mklement0 - did not get how shall I modify my script. Don't I have to specify input file name in Copy-Item ?

Comment: @mklement0 - ok, the script works as expected when I remove FullName and $_ .  Didn't  know you can specify Copy-Item without source file name. Thank you !

Comment: @ggv but you _are_ specifying the source file name - you're just doing so via the pipeline :)

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath -File |
  Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 1 | # Note: No 'FullName'
      Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationPath # Note: No '$_'
```

The simplest and most robust approach is to **pipe `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item` output *as-is* to other file-processing cmdlets**, which binds to the latter's `-LiteralPath` parameter, i.e the input file path.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- The [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), which *explicitly* refers to the pipeline input object at hand, is only needed (and supported) inside [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed to cmdlets.
- With suitable pipeline input, PowerShell *implicitly* binds it to a pipeline-binding parameter of the target cmdlet, which in case of the [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) call above is `-LiteralPath`. In other words: specifying a value for the target parameter as an *argument* isn't necessary.

  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922416/45375) explains the mechanism that binds the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances that [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) outputs to the `-LiteralPath` parameter of file-processing cmdlets such as `Copy-Item`.
  - Note that, with `FullName` out of the picture (see below), it is indeed a `System.IO.FileInfo` instance that `Copy-Item` receives as pipeline input, because the `Sort-Object ...` and `Select-Object -First 1` calls above pass them through without changing their type.
- Selecting the `FullName` property in an attempt to pass only the file's full *path* (as a string) via the pipeline is *unnecessary*, and, more importantly:

  - It *fails*, unless you use `-ExpandProperty FullName` to ensure that only the property *value* is output; without it, you get an *object* that has a `.FullName` *property* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) for more information.
  - Even if you fix that, the solution is - at least hypothetically - *less robust* than passing the `System.IO.FileInfo` instances as a whole: mere *string* input binds to the `-Path` rather than the `-LiteralPath` parameter, which means that what is by definition a *literal* path is interpreted as a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expression, which notably causes mishandling of literal paths that contain `[` characters (e.g. `c:\foo\file[1].txt`).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232707/45375) for how to inspect the specifics of the pipeline-binding parameters of any given cmdlet.