# script runs fine from command line but not from the task scheduler

Tags: powershell, path

I've written a script so I can access my newly recorded media from a podcast player. The script runs as expected from the command line but when it runs from the task scheduler it is not getting the full path from subfolders. There are multiple errors on every foreach pass with this erroneous path. here is one such error

```
get-item : Cannot find path 'D:\Radio\202303100400.mp4' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\jj9wo\mpxtorss.ps1:38 char:23
+ foreach ($folder in ((get-item $media).DirectoryName) | Select-Object ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Radio\202303100400.mp4:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

the correct path to the file is `D:\Radio\kmox\202303100400.mp4`

here is the full script. there is a couple thing that still need work but it is fully functioning except the issue I stated. I know my script favors one-liners and lacks adequate commenting. limiting the critique to my specified problem will be appreciated

```
$path= 'D:\Radio'
$site='mysite.com'
Set-Location -Path $path

if ($path -and $(Try{Test-Path $path.trim()} Catch{}) -and (((get-item $path).Attributes) -match "Directory")){
  $path = Get-Item $path
} else {Write-Host "mp2rss error: Invalid" ;exit}
$media = (Get-ChildItem -path $path -File -Recurse -Filter "*.mp*") | Where-Object `
{$_.extension -in ".mp3",".mp4"} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime
if (!$media.Count){Write-Host "mp2rss error: No Media Found" ;exit}

# done verifying

function when_long($param){
  $param = ($param.AddMinutes(-($param.minute %5)).ToString("h:mmtt ddd, MMM d'th'") -replace
  '(?<!1)1th$','1st' -replace'(?<!1)2th$','2nd' -replace '(?<!1)3th$','3rd') -replace
  '(?<=:\d\d)AM','a' -replace '(?<=:\d\d)PM','p'
  return $param
}
function when_short($param){
  $param = ($param.ToString("ddd"),($param.AddMinutes(-($param.minute %5))).ToString("M/dd h:mmt").ToLower() -join " ")
  return $param
}

if ((Get-Volume -DriveLetter $path.ToString().Substring(0,1)).FileSystemLabel){
    $title_alt = (Get-Volume -DriveLetter $path.ToString().Substring(0,1)).FileSystemLabel
}else{$title_alt = "$env:COMPUTERNAME`($($path.FullName.Substring(0,1))`)"}

if ($path.FullName -eq $path.Root.FullName){
  $title = $title_alt
  $htm_out = "$($path)mpx.htm"
}else{
  $title = $path.BaseName
  $htm_out = "$path\mpx.htm"
}
$html = @("<html><head><title>$title</title></head><body>")

foreach ($folder in ((get-item $media).DirectoryName) | Select-Object -Unique){
  $ext = @('mp3','mp4')
  foreach ($ext in $ext){
    if ($media | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -in $folder -and $_.Extension -match $ext}){

      if ((Get-Item $folder).FullName -ne (Get-Item $folder).Root.FullName){
        $title = (Get-Item $folder).BaseName
      }else{$title = $title_alt}
      if ($ext -match 'mp4'){$title = "$title [V]"}
      $url = (([System.Uri]$folder).AbsoluteUri.TrimStart(([System.Uri]($path.ToString())).AbsoluteUri))
      if ($url){$url = "$site/$url/"}else{$url = "$site/"}
      $qty = (($media | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -in $folder -and $_.Extension -match $ext}) | Measure-Object).Count
      $whn = (when_long ($media | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -in $folder -and $_.Extension -match $ext} | Select-Object -First 1).CreationTime)

      $html += "<p><a href=`"http://$url$ext.rss`">$title</a><br>$qty files updated $whn</p>"
      $rss = @("<rss><channel><title>$title</title>")
      $rss += "<description>$qty files updated $whn</description>"

      foreach ($file in ($media | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -in $folder -and $_.Extension -match $ext})){
        if ($file.BaseName -match "^\d+$"){
          if ($file.BaseName -match "^\d{12}$"){
            $title = (when_short ([Datetime]::ParseExact($file.BaseName, 'yyyyMMddHHmm', $null)))
            $dsc = (when_long ([Datetime]::ParseExact($file.BaseName, 'yyyyMMddHHmm', $null)))
          }else{
            $title = (when_short $file.CreationTime)
            $dsc = (when_long $file.CreationTime)
          }
        }else{
          $title = $file.BaseName
          $dsc = (when_long $file.CreationTime)
        }
        $rss += "<item><title>$title</title>"
        $rss += "<description>$dsc</description>"
        $rss += "<enclosure url=`"http://$url$([uri]::EscapeDataString($file.Name))`"/></item>"
      }
      $rss += "</channel></rss>"
      $rss_out = "$folder\$ext.rss"
      if (-not (Test-Path $rss_out) -or (Compare-Object (Get-Content -Path $rss_out) $rss)){Out-File -InputObject $rss -FilePath $rss_out}
    }
  }
}
if (-not (Test-Path $htm_out) -or (Compare-Object (Get-Content -Path $htm_out) $html)){Out-File -InputObject $html -FilePath $htm_out}
```

Comment: You don't need `Get-Item` here, just do `foreach($folder in $media.DirectoryName |Sort-Object -Unique){...}`

Comment: What account are you using for the Task?  You have data in the C:\Users\jj9wo\mpxtorss.ps1 Only an admin or the user has access to the folder.

Comment: thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, that solved this problem. of course, it uncovered or created others which I will explore

I'm new here. how can I mark your response as a solution?

Comment: @jdweng, I tried multiple configurations, turns out this was not my problem

Comment: What account are you using for the task scheduler?  You must specify an account.  Default account is System which won't have the environment that you need to run code.

Comment: @mrpaulc, now that we know what the problem was, it might help future readers if you remove incidental parts of your lengthy code snippet, so that it is easier to see where the problem occurred.

Comment: It also seems that the use of Task Scheduler is incidental to your problem. If you agree, I suggest removing references to it from the title and question body, so as not to attract future readers who do have an actual Task Scheduler problem.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- There is ***no* need to use `Get-Item` with arguments that already *are* `[System.IO.FileInfo]` (or `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`) instances**, such as output by `Get-ChildItem`.

  - Replace `(Get-Item $media).DirectoryName` with `$media.DirectoryName`
- **In code written for *Windows PowerShell* and in *cross-edition* code, extra effort is needed to use `FileInfo` / `DirectoryInfo` *as strings***:

  - **For targeting *cmdlets*** that accept file paths, **pass `FileInfo` instances *via the pipeline***, which robustly binds `FileInfo` / `DirectoryInfo` instances by their *full path*, to the target cmdlets' `-LiteralPath` parameters - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921220/45375) for background information; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # The [FileInfo] instance robustly binds to 
    # Select-String -LiteralPath by its full path.
    $someFileInfo | Select-String 'foo'
    ```
  - **For targeting *external programs*** / other contexts where you **need a *string* representation of `FileInfo`** instances' *full paths*, use their **`.FullName` property** explicitly; e.g.:

    ```bash
    cmd /c echo The full paths is: $someFileInfo.FullName
    ```

Read on for an explanation.

---

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, using [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) with `$media` is *unnecessary*, because `$media` already contains [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances, due to containing the output from an earlier [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) `-File` call.

Replacing `(Get-Item $media).DirectoryName` with `$media.DirectoryName` is not only simpler and more efficient, but actually *implicitly solves your problem*.

That is, `Get-Item $media` does *not* work as intended *in Windows PowerShell*:

- The `FileInfo` instances are *stringified* in this call. (This part also applies in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).

  - Unlike with pipeline input, when `FileInfo` instances are passed as *arguments*, they are converted to *strings*, because they bind to (positionally) implied `-Path` parameter, which is `[string[]`-typed.
  - As an aside: If you want to prevent accidental interpretation of paths you mean to be *literal* ones as [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), you must use the `-LiteralPath` parameter, explicitly (when providing `FileInfo` / `DirectoryInfo` instances _via the pipeline, this parameter is *implicitly* bound).
    This matters for paths that contain `[` and `]` characters, given that they are *metacharacters* in PowerShell's wildcard language (for defining character ranges and sets).
- In *Windows PowerShell* only, this stringification *situationally* results in only the *name* of the file (`.Name`) rather than its *full path* (`.FullName`) being used to obtain the string representation.

  - Fortunately, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* (.NET (Core)) now *consistently* uses `.FullName`.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for background information.
- Whether `.Name` or `.FullName` stringification occurs depends on the *specifics of the `Get-ChildItem` call* (see the linked answer), and in your case `.Name`-only stringification occurs.

  - Therefore, due to use of `-Recurse`, any `FileInfo` instances found in *subdirectories* of `$path` won't be found by `Get-Item` because the path information is missing due to the `.Name` stringification.
  - In the case at hand:

    - `D:\Radio` is your *current* location, due to the `Set-Location $path` call.
    - The recursive `Get-ChildItem` call then finds file `D:\Radio\kmox\202303100400.mp4`, for instance, and stores its `FileInfo` representation as part of the array in `$media`
    - In the `Get-Item $media` call, that file then stringifies as `202303100400.mp4` *only* (by `.Name`), which - in the absence of *path* information - `Get-Item` tries to resolve against the *current* location (directory).
    - That is, `Get-Item` looks for `D:\Radio\202303100400.mp4` (missing `kmox` path component) - which doesn't exist, and causes the error you saw.