# Convert relative path into absolute string path

Tags: powershell

I need to store a relative path, as an absolute path in a file. I've tried quite a few things, including:

```
$path = (resolve-path -path "C:\Folder\..\Folder2").Path.ToString()

Add-content "d:\textfile.txt" $path
```

Which leaves an empy file. So I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you sure `d:\textfile.txt` is empty?

Comment: Since ``..\`` means to start at current directory parent, this should resolve to `C:\Folder2`. You can do that with `[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd.Path, "C:\Folder\..\Folder2"))`

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure that the file is empty. From what I can find out, resolve-path returns an pathinfo object, which add-content can't write into a file(as it expects a string).

Why .ToString() doesn't work I have no idea.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that the `..` weren't actually there and you just included them for the purposes of the question. Theo's suggestions should help

Comment: You don't need `.ToString()` by the way... the value of `.Path` is already a string by itself. `Resolve-Path` indeed return a path info but `(Resolve-Path ..).Path` return a string so the `.ToString()` is redundant.

Comment: Well, I've tried:

(resolve-path -path "C:\Folder\..\Folder2").Path
(resolve-path -path "c:\Folder\..\Folder2" |  select -ExpandProperty Path 
(convert-Path "c:\Folder\..\Folder2")


All of which result in an empty file(The file does get created, the output just isn't being written to it).

Comment: Missed Theo's comment for some reason. That solved it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to **resolve a *relative* and/or *non-normalized* path** (one with components such as `..` and `.`) **to a *normalized full path***, directly as a *string*, is to **use the [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) cmdlet**:

```bash
Convert-Path -LiteralPath "C:\Folder\..\Folder2"
```

In the context of your command (note that `Add-Content` *appends* to a preexisting target file; to write the given content only, use `Set-Content`):

```bash
Add-Content "d:\textfile.txt" (Convert-Path -LiteralPath "C:\Folder\..\Folder2")
```

Note:

- Unlike [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path), **`Convert-Path` returns a *file-system-native* path**, which is generally preferable.

  - This means that file-system paths that are based on *PowerShell-only drives* (created with `New-PSDrive`) are resolved to the underlying native file-system location, as understood by outside processes too. (E.g., if `MyDrive:` is mapped to `C:\Projects`, `Convert-Path -LiteralPath MyDrive:\Foo` returns `C:\Projects\Foo`)
- Like `Resolve-Path`, `Convert-Path` **requires that the item the path refers to *exist*** - which is an unfortunate limitation, discussed in [GitHub issue #2993](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2993).

---

**If the input path refers to a *nonexistent* file or directory:**

.NET offers the [`[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.GetFullPath) method, which offers the same functionality also for *nonexistent* paths.

The challenge is that relative paths are resolved to *.NET*'s current (working) directory, which *usually differs from PowerShell's* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375) for more information.

In ***PowerShell (Core) 7+***, you can work around this problem by specifying the reference path (to resolve the relative path against) *explicitly*:

```bash
# Note: The 'System.' prefix in the type literal is optional.
[IO.Path]::GetFullPath("C:\Folder\..\Folder2", $PWD.ProviderPath)
```

<sup>The [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) refers to PowerShell's current location (directory). Note the use of `.ProviderPath`, which again ensures uses of a *file-system-native* path. For maximum robustness - to guard agains the case where the current PowerShell location isn't a *file-system* location - use `(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath`.</sup>

In ***Windows PowerShell***, where this method overload isn't available, a more cumbersome approach is needed, as suggested by [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo):

```bash
# Note: If you don't need to *normalize* the path (resolving . and .. components), 
#       the [IO.Path]::Combine() call alone is enough.
[IO.Path]::GetFullPath(
  [IO.Path]::Combine($PWD.ProviderPath, "C:\Folder\..\Folder2")
)
```

- [`[IO.Path]::Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.Combine) *conditionally* combines the first path given with the second one, *if* the latter is *relative* - otherwise, the latter is used as-is.
- `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath()` then ensures *normalization* of the resulting full path (to resolve any `.` and `..` components); if that isn't required, just calling `[IO.Path]::Combine()` will do.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using Resolve-Path over Convert-Path?

Comment: @Blaisem, Resolve-Path is for _PowerShell_ paths and therefore supports all [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers), not just file-system paths. However, for paths based on _PowerShell-only_ file-system drives, it will _not_ resolve to the underlying, _file-system-native path_, which is what you need for passing a path to the outside world (external program or .NET API).

Answer (score 0):

If your path is not existent yet, I found either of the following to work successfully:

```
[IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".\abc")
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(".\abc.txt")
```

Comment: Because .NET's working directory can differ from PowerShell's (it will if you've executed `Set-Location` in your session), `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".\abc")` isn't robust. In PowerShell _Core_ you can fix that with `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".\abc", $PWD.ProviderPath)` . In _Windows PowerShell_, unfortunately, you'll either need `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath([IO.Path]::Combine($PWD.ProviderPath, ".\abc"))` (if path _normalization_ isn't needed, you can omit the  `GetFullPath()` call) or use the "lineful" you're showing as the second option.