# How do I pass currrent directory when only supplying filename?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a module of PS commands written in C#. It communicates with another DLL, that eventually writes a file.

Let's assume Powershell from the Windows Terminal. It starts in `C:\Users\<myname>\`.

`Export-Yadda -filename .\bla.txt` will create a file `bla.txt` in `C:\Users\<myname>\`

When I `cd` to `C:\users\<myname>\foo\` and repeat the command, it will still write to `C:\users\<myname>\`

This has me a at a bit of a loss.

The part of the code that receives the `bla.txt` string could not be simpler, it is just:

```
private string _path;
public string OutputPath
{
    get { return _path; }
    set { _path = value; }
}
```

Magic is being applied to `bla.txt` to make it a FQPN. How do I make it reflect the path the command was issued from? So that I can call it from say `C:\<whatever>` or `E:\temp\`?

Comment: There's no magic. PowerShell's concept of "current directory" doesn't coincide with the *process*'s because the current directory in PowerShell can be non-file system locations, such as the registry. Your module needs to get the current directory from PowerShell.

Comment: .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's, so you should always pass _full, file-system-native_ paths to .NET method calls. Use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) to convert a relative path to a full file-system-native one, assuming it already exists. To specify a file to be created in PowerShell's  current location, use something like `"$PWD\file.txt"`, except from PS-specific drives. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375) to the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The point with the helpful duplicate link is, that in my case, the string passes directly to C# code, so none of the PS trickery applies I think.

Comment: The answer that I unfortunately cannot provide I found in [this repository](https://github.com/fireflycons/PSCloudFormation/blob/57f0dc0a7cdcb54dc95708e2bbd44a7541adae20/src/Firefly.PSCloudFormation/PSPathResolver.cs). The essence is using the `SessionState` from the `PSCmdlet` class.