# Can I get the current console filepath from which a script was invoked from within said script?

Tags: powershell, path, working-directory

If I am in the console/terminal at the `C:\temp` location, and I invoke the script `C:\scripts\test.ps1`, how can I get the path of the current folder (`C:\temp`) from inside the script I just invoked?

None of the following has the required information:

- Get-Location
- $myinvocation
- $pwd
- $PSScriptRoot

Comment: no @jeff... all that solutions except $ExecutionContext I had already try... $ExecutionContext is interesting but unfortunately didn't work too for the presented case!

Comment: I'm not an expert in PowerShell, but I wouldn't expect you would be able to. If you are calling a script it is executed without regard to the location from which it was executed. It only knows the permission context of what it is running under. The script doesn't even know it was called from PowerShell console vs terminal vs as a command in some other application or the ISE, etc. ad infinitum.

Comment: This begs the question, _why_ do you want to know this from inside the script you just executed?

Comment: well @Tyler... to simplify... just imagine you have some .ps1 scripts in the %PATH%... and when you invoke one from the whatever location you are... you want to know this location inside the script.... I hope that from some $context*/$session or even from [.net] we can get that info... that is rather !important ;-)

Comment: That doesn't really explain _why_ you want to know it; it only repeats _that_ you want to know it. What are you expecting to _do_ with the information of where the script was called "from", once you have that information?

Comment: Note to potential close voters: This question is _not_ a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5466329/45375 - the latter is about finding the directory in which the _executing script_ is located, whereas this one is about the _current_ (working) directory.

Comment: @ZEE, your mentioning of `$myinvocation` and `$PSScriptRoot` added to the confusion (they relate to the script being invoked, not to the current directory). `$pwd` and an argument-less `Get-Location` call _do_ report PowerShell's current _location_ (and would indeed work if `C:\temp` is the current location), which generally may or may not be a _directory_, however. Separately, there is the _process_' working directory, as seen by .NET API calls. The answer now (hopefully) covers all angles. Let us know if you think something is unclear or missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- The **next section** discusses ***PowerShell*'s notion of what the current (working) directory is**, which is *specific to PowerShell*.

  - **`$pwd` and `Get-Location` *typically* work - but not always**: see below.
- By contrast, if you want to know **what the *current process* sees as its current directory**, which notably **applies to calls to *.NET APIs***, use **`[Environment]::CurrentDirectory`** - this is typically *not* what PowerShell sees as its current location.

  - The reason for this discrepancy, which is rooted in PowerShell's ability to host *multiple runspaces* (threads) in a single process, is explained in [GitHub issue #3428](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428)

    - Therefore, **robustly calling .NET APIs (in-process) currently requires passing *full*, native file-system paths** - see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375)
    - However, calls to *external programs* are *not* affected, because PowerShell *does* set its notion of the current file-system directory as the working directory of the *child process* that is invariably created for external programs.
  - Follow-up [GitHub issue #17149](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17149) ponders synchronizing PowerShell's current (file-system) location with that of the process *for the foreground runspace, specifically* in the *future*, starting with an [experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features); the latter has not yet been implemented as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.6

---

###### PowerShell's current *location* vs. its current *directory*, PowerShell-specific vs. native file-system paths:

**tl;dr**

- `$PWD` (equivalent to calling `Get-Location` without arguments) will *typically* - but not necessarily - reflect PowerShell's current file-system location (working directory).

  - The fully robust solution for returning a string that expresses the working directory as file-system-native path is:

    ```bash
    (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
    ```
- With use of `$PWD` / argument-less `Get-Location`, additional considerations apply with respect to (a) whether the resulting object even represents a *file-system* location, and (b) even if so, whether its *form* is understood by *external programs*.

Read on for background information.

---

[`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location) reports PowerShell's *current location*, which, however, isn't guaranteed to be a *file-system* location, given that a PowerShell [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) *other* than the [`FileSystem` provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_FileSystem_Provider) could be the one underlying the current [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Locations) - even though that is rare in practice.

Therefore, to *robustly* determine the full path of the current *file-system* location, use the following:

```bash
(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).Path
```

Note that the above expresses the file-system location potentially in terms of *PowerShell-only* drives, namely if the path passed to [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) was expressed in terms of a drive created with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive).

Therefore, to robustly determine the full path of the current file-system location as a *native* file-system path, use `.ProviderPath` instead of `.Path`:

```bash
# .ProviderPath only differs from .Path if the current
# file-system location is on a PowerShell-only drive
# (a non-persistent drive established with New-PSDrive)
(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
```

In the simplest case - if you're willing to assume that the current location is a *file-system* location - you can use the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd), which is in effect a more efficient alternative to calling `Get-Location` without arguments.

```bash
# Same as: (Get-Location).Path
$PWD.Path  # same as: "$PWD" (stringified)
```

Note:

- *Stringifying* a [`System.Management.Automation.PathInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PathInfo) instance - as reported by `$PWD` / `Get-Location` - results in the value of its `.Path` property, so situationally you may not need to access the `.Path` property explicitly; e.g., `"The current location is: $PWD"`
- As noted, the `.ProviderPath` (e.g. `$PWD.ProviderPath`) returns the *native* file-system path (for instances representing the paths to items of the `FileSystem` provider; more generally, it returns the form of the path that is native to the underlying provider).

Comment: What would the outcome of each call be in the context of OP's situation? Would it be `C:\temp` for all three commands?

Comment: @TylerH, yes, given that `C:\temp` is a file-system-native path, `$PWD.Path`/ `(Get-Location).Path` and `$PWD.ProviderPath` / `(Get-Location).ProviderPath` all return `C:\temp`. I've updated the answer to make that clearer, along with a tr;dl section.

Comment: thanks mklement0; [Environment]::CurrentDirectory is the answer... but your complete and exhaustive answer for sure contributed to clarify the subject...

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ZEE. It's tricky business, for sure.