# Powershell Question How to Select Specific Characters in a File's Name?

Tags: powershell, wildcard, string-matching

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that looks for just files with the extension .dgn within a specific directory.  Then if it has a character string of "_ch_" in the name of the file it will delete it.  Else it will move the file to a new directory.

```
        Function Remove-ExtraneousCADFiles {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    
    Param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $paths
    )
    
    Begin {Clear-Host}
    
    Process {
    $char = "_ch_"
    $fileName = Split-Path $input -leaf
    $destDir = "D:\CRASH\ACCID - Lite Test\"
    Write-Output ("fileName= " + $fileName)
    Write-Output ("char= " + $char)
    Write-Output ("_.Name= " + $_.Name)
    
    #if ($_.contains($char)) {
    
    #if (Where $_.Name -Match $char) {
    
    #if ($_.Name -Match $char) {
    
    if ($_.Name -Like $char) {
    Remove-Item $_ -Force -Confirm -WhatIf
    Write-Output ("Delete= " + $fileName.Name)
    }
    else {
    #Write-Output ("Move _.FullName= " + $_.FullName)
    #Write-Output ("destDir= " + $destDir)
    #Write-Output ("_.BaseName= " + $_.BaseName)
    #Write-Output ("_.Extension= " + $_.Extension)
    #Write-Output ""
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ($destDir + $_.BaseName + $_.Extension) -WhatIf
    Write-Output ""
    }
    }
    
    End {}
    
    }

$inputPath = "D:\CRASH\ACCID - Lite Test zzz"
(Get-ChildItem -Path $inputPath -Recurse -Include *.dgn) | Remove-ExtraneousCADFiles
```

But I can't get the "IF" portion of my script to pass anything to the Remove-Item or Write-Output command.  I've try other commands but I'm not having any luck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

These are an example of the files I'm trying to weed out to either delete or move:
[image]

Thanks, G

---

Comment: Wouldn't something like this do what you described in the your first paragraph? `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\Temp' -Recurse -Filter '*.dgn' | ForEach-Object {if($_.Name -match $_.Name -match '^.*_ch_.*$') {<# Code to delete file $_ #>} else {<# Code to move file $_ #>}}`

Comment: As an aside: You're declaring `$paths` (better :`$Path` (singular)) as the pipeline-binding parameter, so it's better to use _it_ - not `$input` - in your `process` block.

Comment: @Darin, I will experiment with your suggestion of using a 'pipeline' format of my script.  I'm not that familiar with its formatting.

Comment: @mklement0, Yes that of course makes sense thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$_.Name -Like $char`

**`-like` uses [*wildcard expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards)**, which must **match the input *as a whole***.

Therefore, enclose your substring in `*...*`:

```bash
$_.Name -like "*$char*"
```

---

Alternatively use **`-match`**, which matches ***part* of the input** by default (*substring* matching):

```bash
$_.Name -match $char
```

However, note that `-match` uses  [*regular expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) (regexes), so if your - designed to be used *verbatim* - search string happens to contain regex *metacharacters* (e.g., `.`, `+`), you'll have to *escape* them (not necessary in your case):

```bash
$_.Name -match [regex]::Escape($char)
```

---

Note:

- **Direct use of *.NET APIs*** also allows you to use the `[string]` type's. **[`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Contains) method**, which uses ***case-exact substring matching*** by default.

  - That is, `$_.Name.Contains($char)` does work for ***case-exact* matching**.
- However, this is **at odds with PowerShell's fundamentally case-*insensitive* nature**:

  - *invariably* so in *Windows PowerShell*: there is no overload with a case-insensitivity opt-in.
  - in **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** you can use a *newly introduced overload* of `.Contains()` that permits **case-*insensitive* matching on an *opt-in* basis**, via an *additional parameter*, e.g.:

    ```bash
    # PowerShell (Core) v7+ only
    'foo'.Contains('OO', 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase') # -> $true
    ```
- While **direct use of .NET APIs is a viable option** - which is a testament to PowerShell's versatility - the flip side is that **doing so is *not PowerShell-idiomatic***, for two reasons:

  - By default, .NET APIs are case-*sensitive* , whereas PowerShell is case-*insensitive*.
  - Calling .NET APIs:

    - requires *method syntax* (enclosure of arguments in `(...)`, separating arguments with `,` - e.g, `[double]::Parse('1.2', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`), which contrasts with PowerShell's shell-like *argument*-[parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) (e.g., `Get-Date -Year 1963`) as well as the use of PowerShell's *operators* in *expression*-parsing mode (e.g; `1.2 + 1`)
    - requires passing *full file paths* to .NET APIs, given that .NET's notion of the *current directory* usually differs from PowerShell's - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375).

Comment: Thank You Very Much for your suggestions and detailed explanation of each.  Very Helpful and illuminating, Peace.