# Powershell [xml] Save does not work correctly with relative paths

Tags: powershell, .net-core

In Powershell, typing the following two lines results in a failure.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content ~/.m2/settings.xml)
$xml.Save("~/.m2/settings.xml")
```

Results in the following error.

```
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): 

"Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\Users\craig\~\.m2\settings.xml'."
```

I am using the latest version of powershell, namely 7.3.8.

(Perhaps there's an alternative to using the save method, but I cannot find one that works?)

Comment: ```~``` (tilde) is a *powershell* shorthand notation that means the current user's home path, which is why ```Get-Content``` works to load the file. However, the "native" dotnet ```Save``` method doesn't support this same convenience so it's treating it as a literal folder name relative to the current working directory. You can use ```Resolve-Path``` to convert your relative *powershell* path into a fully qualified filesystem path using this: ```$xml.Save((Join-Path (Resolve-Path "~").Path ".m2/settings.xml"))```

Comment: Do you want to post that as an answer. It’s a good suggestion.

Comment: Done (I wasn't in a position to write a fully-fledged answer previously so just left it as a comment)

Comment: Note that a path starting with `~` isn't a _relative_ path: it is an absolute one that happens to use a placeholder for the full path of the user's home directory. Actual relative paths, such as `.\settings.xml` must be avoided too, for the reasons explained in the next comment:

Comment: .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's, so you should always pass _full, file-system-native_ paths to .NET method calls. Use [`Convert-Path`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) to convert a relative path to a full file-system-native one, assuming it already exists. To specify a file to be created in PowerShell's  current location, use something like `"$PWD\file.txt"`, except from PS-specific drives. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375) to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` (tilde) in a file path is a PowerShell-specific convenience that means the current user's home path in **built-in** cmdlets - see **Example 1** in the [documentation for Resolve-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-7.3#example-1-resolve-the-home-folder-path):

> #### Example 1: Resolve the home folder path
>
> The tilde character (~) is shorthand notation for the current user's home folder. This example shows Resolve-Path returning the fully qualified path value.
>
> **PowerShell**
>
> ```
> PS C:\> Resolve-Path ~
>
> Path
> ----
> C:\Users\User01
> ```

It's built into a lot of PowerShell cmdlets (`Resolve-Path`, `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Content` that I've tested, but probably more) but only seems to really be mentioned at all in the documentation for `Resolve-Path`.

This is why your `$xml = [xml](Get-Content ~/.m2/settings.xml)` works - PowerShell is resolving the `~` and reading from the appropriate fully qualified path.

However, the "native" dotnet `Save` method doesn't support this same convenience so it's treating it as a literal folder name relative to the current working directory.

You can use `Convert-Path` (thanks @mklement0 for the correction :-)) to convert your PowerShell-specific path into a fully qualified filesystem path using this:

```
$path = Join-Path (Convert-Path "~") ".m2/settings.xml"
$xml.Save($path)
```

or simply

```
$xml.Save((Join-Path (Convert-Path "~").Path ".m2/settings.xml"))
```

Note that you can't *safely* use `Convert-Path` on your full path unless you know the target file already exists, because it will fail if it doesn't exist (and presumably there might be cases where your file *doesn't* exist to start with):

```
PS> Convert-Path "~/.m2/settings.xml"
Convert-Path: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Mike\.m2\settings.xml' because it does not exist.
```

As a result, the previous example only resolves the `~` tilde and then uses `Join-Path` (which *doesn't* verify if the path exists) to append the remaining file path.

### Caveat

Both `Resolve-Path` and `Convert-Path` use the *current* PSProvider to perform operations, so you need to have the `FileSystem` provider selected for this to work - basically `Set-Location` to a filesystem path rather than, e.g. the `Registry` provider - see below for a broken example:

```
PS ...> Set-Location "D:\"
PS D:\> Convert-Path "~"
C:\Users\Mike

PS C:\> Set-Location "HKLM:"
PS HKLM:> Convert-Path "~"
Convert-Path: Home location for this provider is not set. To set the home location, call "(get-psprovider 'Registry').Home = 'path'".
```

You can use `Push-Location` to ensure you're working on a FileSystem path and then `Pop-Location` after to return the location back to wherever it was beforehand...

Comment: @mklement0 - thanks, as ever :-). Btw, I spotted a very unlikely edge case re the current provider - I've added a note to call it out though...

Comment: My pleasure; thanks for updating. Yes, it's unfortunate that `~` is provider-specific; the robust alternative is `"$HOME/..."`