# Wrapping a PowerShell Program in a Batch File and Using "Set-Location" Returns Root

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, directory

The following code worked perfectly-

```
$ScriptLocation = Get-Location
Set-Location "$ScriptLocation"
```

...until I created a batch file to kick the script off. I understand that by opening the script via the batch file the location will be the root directory.

My question is, how can I set the current directory to the directory where the script is when launching the script from a batch file?

My batch file has the following code-

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ScriptDirectory=%~dp0
SET ScriptPath=%ScriptDirectory%FilePush_V0.1.ps1 
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""%ScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's something wildly wrong with this question since it was voted down?

Comment: See [whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466329/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script



    set-Location $PSScriptRoot
    cd..

Comment: That seems to work, thank you. How about setting it to go up one directory afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

```
set-Location $PSScriptRoot
cd..
```

See the following for your version of powershell.

[whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466329/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script)

Comment: This wouldn't work for me on PS v2. I ended up using  
-`$ScriptLocation = Split-Path  -Parent$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition`  
-`$ScriptRunPath = Split-Path -Path $ScriptLocation -Parent`  
-`Set-Location "$ScriptRunPath"`

Ugh, how do I add line breaks? Double spaces don't work.