# Powershell copy-item issue

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have a very weird issue and been pulling my hair out.

I have two PowerShell scripts.
Lets say Main and child. Child script is in a folder within mainfolder:

```
Mainfolder\Main_script    
MainFolder\ChildFolder\child_script.ps1
```

The Main script runs from where the location can change. So I get the location of the script in the beginning

```
$ScriptDir = (Get-Location).path
```

I do some tasks including copying which works

```
copy-item -path $src -Destination $dst -force
```

Everything till this point is great. 
Then I call my child script

```
& "$scriptdir\childfolder\Child_script.ps1"
```

The scripts runs, and I see other tasks being executed. But I have some files in the child folder that I need to copy over. But the copy doesn't work with the child_Script. 
I even put

```
"Copying $src to $destination" | Out-file -append $logfile
```

and I see `Copying C:\test\copythis.txt to C:\temp`

The code in the childscript is this

```
$Scriptdir = (Get-Location).path
$src =  "$Scriptdir\copythis.txt"
$dst = "C:\temp"
copy-item -path $src -Destination $dst -force
```

If I try to copy the same files in the main script, everything works.Why does the copy-item doesn't work in the childscript?
I should also mention that everything is running with the system account. So No permission issues.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Cheers,

Comment: Can you post the whole content of `child_script.ps1` or at least the part where you try to copy the files? Also, what do you do with the `$ScriptDir`? Be aware that this is not the location where your script is located!

Comment: Hi Jisaak, The code is long but basically what I posted above is basically what it is for the copying part(edited). The items that I want to copy are in the child folder so thats why I do the $Scriptdir once more. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849835.aspx):

> Get-Location
>   Gets information about the current working location or a location stack.

....

> The Get-Location cmdlet gets an object that represents the current directory, much like the pwd (print working directory) command.

If you want to use the directory in which the script is located use the answer from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466329/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script).

Comment: Hi Bas, Letme try this and get back to you. Thanks for your reply,