# How can I specify a path relative to where my script is running?

Tags: powershell

I have this:

```
 Get-ChildItem c:\H\admin\contents
```

Is it possible to do the same thing but relative to the folder that the powershell script runs in.  Sometimes I have the script running in c\H\admin and sometimes in the c\H\user directory so I would prefer not to have to change all the paths in my scripts.

Comment: Similar post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466329/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use relative paths.

```
Get-ChildItem .
```

refers to the current directory, `c:\H\admin\contents`.

```
Get-ChildItem ..
```

refers to the parent directory, `c:\H\admin`

```
Get-ChildItem ..\..
```

refers to the parent of the parent, `c:\H`

You can use relative paths related to a specific path:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\H\admin\..\users
```

which would refer to the folder `c:\H\users`

Comment: There has to be a dupe for this.

Comment: @Matt: Apparently you didn't find one, or you would have voted to close the question instead of commenting on an answer. :-) Thanks for your support.

Comment: Not so fast.... I am looking for one.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the information. Can I look at every answer you've ever posted that might have a dupe as well, and inform you every step of the way? Or, better yet: Can I ask why you're telling *me* that the poster may have posted a duplicate, rather than telling the poster? I didn't post the question.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware there is nothing wrong with dupes... I'm sure there are a bunch of mine somewhere especially the earlier ones. It doesn't make the answers wrong? Body language is lost in text but I didn't think I was saying anything wrong... Sorry about that.