# How to find location/path of current script in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script (script1.ps1) that lies in C:\FolderA

What powershell code can I insert in the script, that it will print what ever current location/path of the script. (The goal is to make this script portable)

ie:

-When in folderA, the code will print C:\FolderA (full-path)

-When Script1.ps1 is moved to C:\FolderB\FolderC and run, it prints the full path of C:\FolderB\FolderC

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

---

Thanks to @Nkosi and @Kori Gill

The answer I was looking for was $PSScriptRoot

One thing to note, is that I noticed I had to define a variable first inside the script before running the script:

```
$Path = $PSScriptRoot

$Path
```

with this it worked otherwise it didnt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to determine the location of the current PowerShell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466329/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See "get-help about_Automatic_Variables".

Read sections on:

- $MyInvocation
- $PSScriptRoot
- $PSCommandPath

Comment: At least for me, I had to first run `Update-Help` as admin before this command would work.  Otherwise, use the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: I had to first run also this command from Admin PS Console:
`Install-Script -Name Install-AboutHelp`
from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654102/get-help-about-automatic-variables-not-working) other question.