# Is it possible to get the caller's directory in PowerShell script when calling from CMD or batch file?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I type this in CMD from `C:\source`:

```
powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File C:\test\test.ps1
```

In `test.ps1` I try to get `C:\source` as directory without success.

```
$script_folder = $PSScriptRoot
$myDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$myDir
$PSScriptRoot
```

Both `$myDir` and `$PSScriptRoot` returns `C:\test\` instead of `C:\source`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$PWD` which is the Automatic variable for Present Working Directory. When you open PowerShell it should continue to use the same working directory.

From [about_automatic_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

> $PWD
>
> Contains a path object that represents the full path of the current directory.

Also MS-DOS is an Operating System which cannot run PowerShell. This is different from cmd.exe aka Command Prompt in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic variables you are using are information about the script invocation.  The location from which the command to launch the script was initiated is part of the environment.

`$PWD` contains information about the present working directory (nod to posix `pwd` command).  Specifically, `$PWD.Path`.

Per the [`about_automatic_variables` page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) (or `Get-Help about_automatic_variables)`, `$PSScriptRoot`, `$PSCommandPath`, are properties of `$MyInvocation`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23072876/4446881) for an example of using `Split-Path -Path $($Global:$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)` to get the current path.

Recommend a test script:

```
# TestInvocationAndPWDPaths.ps1
function Test-MyInvocation {
    $MyInvocation  
}
function Test-PWD {
    $PWD
}
'$MyInvocation from script:'
$MyInvocation
'$MyInvocation from function:'
Test-MyInvocation

'$PWD from script:'
$PWD
'$PWD from function'
Test-PWD
```

Has interesting results.  Running this from powershell console, and from ISE, and from command prompt will show you the differences in $MyInvocation.

Answer (score 1):

$MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot gives you the caller scripts folder.
When the caller is command line, this will return $null.

You should be able to use these two facts.

Just want to add that it is a general pitfall in powershell to use $pwd/get-location inside psm1 functions.
Instead inject the full paths as parameters.