# Path Variable in PS1 Script - If PS1 is executed via CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd, location

I try to elevate a Script by using a batch :

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0main.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

That works fine but the thing is i use a variable in the Script to merge certain paths so i can use the folders within the Folder in which the script is located.

`$temppath = Get-Location | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path`

```
Scriptfolder
      |_____Script
      |_____BackupFolder
      |_____Profilfolder
```

So what i do is if i need to access on of the folders in a functin i do something like

`$backuppath = $temppath + "\BackupFolder"`

To make it at least a bit dynamic. The logic problem now is if i execute the Script via the Batch the location that i will  will be some system32 path not the origin path of the script because i call it via the prompt.

How could i make it less dependend but still so dynamic that i could run it from everywhere with only the condtion of having the folders in the same location as the script.

Comment: Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466355/11942268) help?

Comment: Yea it did ...i forogt that i can use that ...because you cant use it if you just run the script from ISE directly - urgh *facepalm*