# Powershell import-module doesn't find modules

Tags: powershell, module

I'm learning PowerShell and I'm trying to build my own module library.

I've written a simple module `XMLHelpers.psm1` and put in my folder `$home/WindowsPowerShell/Modules`.

When I do:

```
 import-module full_path_to_XMLHelpers.psm1
```

It works. But when I do:

```
import-module XMLHelpers
```

It doesn't work and I get the error:

> Import-Module : The specified module 'xmlhelpers' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

I've checked that the environment variable `PSModulePath` contains this folder. As it is a network folder, I've also tried to move it to a local folder and to modify `PSModulePath` but without success

```
 $env:PSModulePath=$env:PSModulePath+";"+'C:\local'
```

Any idea on what could cause this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14382579/299327 seems like it's related.

Answer (score 115):

The module needs to be placed in a folder with the same name as the module. In your case:

```
$home/WindowsPowerShell/Modules/XMLHelpers/
```

The full path would be:

```
$home/WindowsPowerShell/Modules/XMLHelpers/XMLHelpers.psm1
```

You would then be able to do:

```
import-module XMLHelpers
```

Comment: Thanks it does work. Do I need for each module to follow the rule module_name/module_name.psm1 ?

Comment: @Serge: Yes, every separate module is like that.

Comment: Yes, unless you use the full path in the `Import-Module` statement. You can also organize functions into multiple .psm1 files and have them loaded by a Module Manifest file (.psd1). In this case the .psd1 and multiple .psm1 files would sit under the same "module_name/" directory. Only the .psd1 file would need to have the same name as the module.

Comment: You can also use:
`import-module .\XMLHelpers.psm1`

Comment: This could be made clearer in the docs.  The folder structure was the part I was missing.

Answer (score 22):

1.This will search XMLHelpers/XMLHelpers.psm1 in current folder

```
Import-Module (Resolve-Path('XMLHelpers'))
```

2.This will search XMLHelpers.psm1 in current folder

```
Import-Module (Resolve-Path('XMLHelpers.psm1'))
```

Comment: Very nice for when you are developing and debugging your module

Answer (score 12):

I think that the `Import-Module` is trying to find the module in the default directory `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`.

Try to put the full path, or copy it to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

Comment: That's only one location it looks. There are others. See `$env:PSModulePath`.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same error and tried numerous things before I succeeded. The solution was to prepend the path of the script to the relative path of the module like this:

```
// Note that .Path will only be available during script-execution
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Import-Module $ScriptPath\Modules\Builder.psm1
```

Btw you should take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284(v=vs.85).aspx which states:

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, modules are imported automatically when any cmdlet or function in the module is used in a command. This feature works on any module in a directory that this included in the value of the PSModulePath environment variable ($env:PSModulePath)

Comment: This would only work if the `Modules` directory happens to be in the same location as the script.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, but only in Visual Studio Code, not in ISE. Turns out I was using an x86 session in VSCode. I displayed the PowerShell Session Menu and switched to the x64 session, and all the modules began working without full paths. I am using Version 1.17.2, architecture x64 of VSCode. My modules were stored in the **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules** directory.

Comment: omg! I had this exact issue! Thank you so much David!

Comment: (Old post, I know)
Just a note you normally shouldn't be modifying that directory: That's what's shipped w/  Windows Powershell (older versions). Added, system-wide modules would by default go to %ProgramFiles%\(PSVersionDependent)\Modules, so
`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
(Versions up to 5) or
`C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules`
(Ver 6 or higher) on default English installs.

Answer (score 3):

Some plugins require one to run as an `Administrator` and will not load unless one has those credentials active in the shell.

Answer (score 2):

My finding with PS 5.0 on Windows 7: `$ENV:PsModulePath` has to end with a . This normally means it will load all modules in that path.

I'm not able to add a single module to $env:PsModulePath and get it to load with `Import-Module ExampleModule`. I have to use the full path to the module. e.g. `C:\MyModules\ExampleModule`. I am sure it used to work.

For example: 
Say I have the modules:

```
C:\MyModules\ExampleModule
C:\MyModules\FishingModule
```

I need to add `C:\MyModules\` to `$env:PsModulePath`, which will allow me to do

```
Import-Module ExampleModule
Import-Module FishingModule
```

If for some reason, I didn't want `FishingModule`, I thought I could add `C:\MyModules\ExampleModule` only (no trailing \), but this doesn't seem to work now. To load it, I have to `Import-Module C:\MyModules\ExampleModule`

Interestingly, in both cases, doing `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, shows the modules, but it won't import. Although, the module's cmdlets seem to work anyway.

AFAIK, to get the automatic import to work, one has to add the name of the function to FunctionsToExport in the manifest (.psd1) file. Adding `FunctionsToExport = '*'`, breaks the auto load. You can still have `Export-ModuleMember -Function *` in the module file (.psm1).

These are my findings. Whether there's been a change or my computer is broken, remains to be seen. HTH

Answer (score 2):

try with below on powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
import-module [\path\]XMLHelpers.psm1
```

Instead of [] put the full path

Full explanation of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) and [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check Your account type,some imports are not allowed to normal partner accounts.