# relative path in Import-Module

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
C:\TFS\MasterScript\Script1.ps1
C:\TFS\ChildScript\Script2.ps1
```

What I want to do is specify the relative path in Script2.ps1 to look for Script1.ps1 in the directory hierarchy.

This is what I tried in Script2.ps1:

```
Import-Module ../MasterScript/Script1.ps1
```

but it does not work and says it cannot find the module.

If I say `Import-Module C:\TFS\MasterScript\Script1.ps1`, it works fine.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to import anything in script1.ps1 as I have tried this and it works fine?

Comment: Try adding -verbose to your import to see if that throws up any clues.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

When you use a relative path, it is based off the currently location (obtained via Get-Location) and not the location of the script.  Try this instead:

```
$ScriptDir = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Import-Module $ScriptDir\..\MasterScript\Script.ps1
```

In PowerShell v3, you can use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` in scripts to simplify this to:

```
# PowerShell v3 or higher

#requires -Version 3.0
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\MasterScript\Script.ps1
```

Comment: you answer is great however when i says Write-Host $scriptDir, it displays C:\TFS\ChildScript. Is there a way to go one more level up and get C:\TFS in there? I added one $scriptDir1 = Split-Path -Parent $scriptDir and it gives me C:\TFS which is what i want but was wondering if i can add some sort of "level up" argument to the first statement.

Comment: never mind. i added one more pipe at the end. Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split -parent. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `join-path` would be better than adding backslashes yourself.

Answer (score 18):

The new Method for this is `$PSScriptRoot`

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Script1.ps1
```

Nice little one liner.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```powershell
$selfPath = (Get-Item -Path "." -Verbose).FullName
$dllRelativePath = "........"
$dllAbsolutePath = Join-Path $selfPath $dllRelativePath
Import-Module $dllAbsolutePath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `using module ..\path\to\module` on the top of any PowerShell script file.

The path is always relative to the script you put the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using) in.

> **NOTE:** Always use backslashes as the path separator. Even in Linux.