# I want to load modules from a relative path so that it will work when script is run from the a cmd prompt, inside the PowerShell Repl and ISE

Tags: powershell

I would like to be able to modularize my PowerShell scripts such that I put private modules in a local "lib" folder, and then load them from my scripts.  Example:

```
Import-Module $base\lib\constants.psm1 -Force
Import-Module $base\lib\getUserEntries.psm1 -Force
Import-Module $base\lib\utilitiesNetwork.psm1 -Force
```

What would be the definition of `$base` ?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [relative path in Import-Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382579/relative-path-in-import-module)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, but it seems contrived -- seems like there ought to be a better way to do this considering how common this Use Case is.  So the top of one of my scripts will look like this:

```
$base=$(if ($psISE) {Split-Path -Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath} else {$(if ($global:PSScriptRoot.Length -gt 0) {$global:PSScriptRoot} else {$global:pwd.Path})})

Import-Module $base\lib\constants.psm1 -Force
Import-Module $base\lib\getUserEntries.psm1 -Force
Import-Module $base\lib\utilitiesNetwork.psm1 -Force
```

Is there a better way?