# Error importing virtualenvwrapper to the Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have python  2.7 installed perfectly, and also pip, and I have been running the PowerShell as admin.

I did:

*pip install virtualenv*

and

*pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell*

and they both were succesfull.

I also did this:

*mkdir '~.virtualenvs'*

However, whenever I try to:

*Import-Module virtualenvwrapper*

it always gets me this error:
**Import-Module: The specific module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.**

I did *pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell* again just to make sure, and I got this:
**Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper-powershell in c:\python27\lib\site-packages**

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Does @Techek [solution work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412921/powershell-import-module-doesnt-find-modules) for you?

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem when I tried to do the exact same thing as what you did. Finally I figured it out. I found that the virtualenvwrapper I installed is somehow not in the current folder (C:). Instead, it is hidden in the folder:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Users\*myusername*\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\VirtualEnvWrapper
```

I recommend you go to your Python folder and try to search something like

```
"\Lib\site-packages\Users\*myusername*\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\"
```

and if you can find the module **VirtualEnvWrapper** there, then when you type the command, you just need to include the complete path.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You must be following the setup instructions for http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows. Me too. Here is how I fixed it:

1. From Powershell, type "Get-ChildItem Env:PSModulePath"
   The value of this variable tells you the folder that Powershell looks when importing modules.
2. pip installed my module to "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Users\\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper"
3. Copy that folder to the folder from step #1
4. Restart Powershell

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out so much

After going to pc -> C: -> Python27 -> Lib -> site-packages -> users -> 
 * your user * -> WindowsPowerShell -> Modules -> Copy the VirtualEnvWrapper

In a self made directory in Documents call it WindowsPowerShell and then make another inside it called Modules Copy the VirtualEnvWrapper folder within this.

then drop a set-executionpolicy unrestricted in CMD as ADMINISTRATOR !!!

followed by a Import-Module virtualenvwrapper

and you should be 100%

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040546/5185974

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today on a fresh win 10 system. For some reason the VirtualEnvWrapper seems to create a User folder in the site-packages folder inside your Python installation, where it can't be found. Just moving the "Modules" with all its content did the trick.
-> (in my case from:)
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Users\*USER*\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\**Modules**\VirtualEnvWrapper`

-> to `C:\Users\*USER*\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\**Modules**\VirtualEnvWrapper`
..did the trick... where your powershell profile can find it ;)