# Installing virtualenvwrapper-powershell in Windows 8.1, import-module failing

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to follow the guide [here](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows), and I'm stuck at `Import-Module virtualenvwrapper`, where PowerShell keeps giving me the error:

> import-module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not
>   loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - import-module virtualenvwrapper
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

I'm at a real loss at what to do here, because as far as I can tell from this guide and others this step should be rather straight-forward. Googling this problem hasn't really helped me here since I can't find anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I've actually figured my way around this issue. I guess the pip install never placed the files in a correct module directory for PowerShell. I created a `WindowsPowerShell\Modules` folder in my documents folder, which did not exist but was listed in my PowerShell modules path. I then took the VirtualEnvWrapper directory from [the virtualenvwrapper-powershell bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/guillermooo/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/src/58ebd8fcd394340397eb310f77a76f110fad7b6f?at=default) and copied it into the Modules folder I just created.

Then I had to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` instead of `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` as shown in the guide, but I was then able to do the import-module and use everything needed. I'm not sure why I had to all of this manually instead of pip having done it, but I just hope this can somehow help someone else.

Comment: in my case, there was a `Users` directory created in `Lib\site-packages` that contained the modules that needed to be moved to `WindowsPowerShell\Modules` in my documents folder. So, the same steps as above except downloading from bitbucket

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for coming back with a solution. This helped me today. I would also like to add that I had to do an extra step to make it work on Windows 10.

I was getting an error trying to run:

> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper

*"Get-Content : Cannot find path 'Function:\TabExpansion' because it does not exist."*

The solution that I found, was to edit VirtualenvWrapperTabExpansion.psm1 on line 15 from this:

```
$_oldTabExpansion = Get-Content Function:TabExpansion
```

to this:

```
$_oldTabExpansion = Get-Content Function:TabExpansion2
```