# Import-Module virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenvwrapper

I am using powershell.
I successfully installed virtualenvwrapper-powershell.

But when I typed 'Import-Module virtualenvwrapper', I got an error as following:

> > PS C:\Python27> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper Import-Module : The
> >     specified module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not loaded because no valid
> >     module file was found in any module directory. At line:1 char:1
> >
> > Import-Module virtualenvwrapper ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >     CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper:String)
> >     [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> >     Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

It would be great if you could give me some advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either store the module in a folder with the same name as the module or you need to use `.psm1` with the import command. For your case, you need to store the module in the following path

```
C:/Python27/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.psm1
```

and therefore you can use this command

```
Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
```

or call your module using this command

```
Import-Module virtualenvwrapper.psm1
```

If neither of these works, then you might find this link helpful 
[installing virtualenvwrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035903/installing-virtualenvwrapper-powershell-in-windows-8-1-import-module-failing)

Comment: Thanks Ala, I followed your advice. But the same error still happens..

PS C:\python27> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper.psm1 Import-Module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory. At line:1 char:1 + Import-Module virtualenvwrapper.psm1 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundExcept ion + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: @SuzukiSoma can you actually see the virtualenvwrapper.psm1 file directly under C:/Python27 directory?. If no, which is mostly the case, then you need to write the full path to the module. For example, if your module in C:/PowershellModules, then you need to say this Import-Module C:\PowershellModules\virtualenvwrapper.psm1

Comment: yes! there is definitely a file 'virtualenvwrapper.psm1' under directly "C:\Python27" ..

Comment: OMG, I reffered exactly same page as him (http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows)

Comment: Ok! I will try to followe the step which the page you provided shows

Comment: @SuzukiSoma If your powershell scripts are unsigned and you are on a strict execution policy you won't be able to import the module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste the VirtualEnvWrapper folder in the following directory. It works for me

**

> `
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

`

**