# How do you run "Install-Module" in a PowerShell Script in a .NET runtime in AWS Lambda?

Tags: powershell, .net-core, aws-lambda, terraform, gitlab-ci

I have a powershell script running in a .NET Core 3.1 (C#/PowerShell) runtime in AWS.  I'm unable to use `Install-Module` to install modules.  When I try, for example, to run `Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement` I get the following error:

`[Error] - The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

How do I get around this?  I'm deploying my code from a local project using terraform and gitlab-ci.  Do I need to somehow include the modules in my project itself so that they get zipped up and deployed with my script?

UPDATE:

I tried adding a '/modules' folder to the '/lambda_code' folder of my lambda project (and manually pasted the desired module into that folder).  Now when I run 'Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement' I get:

`[Error] - The specified module 'ExchangeOnlineManagement' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.`

It seems I am not putting the module in the right path.

I added the following logs to my script to discover where to put the module:

```
$modulePath = $ENV:PSModulePath
Write-host "This is the PSModulePath ${modulePath}"
```

Which printed:
`[Information] - This is the PSModulePath /tmp/765bd878-da6c-4275-a378-78de284fb3e3/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/var/task/Modules`

I don't see how to use that information.  Input is welcomed!  thank you.

```
[Information] - 
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.0
OS                             Linux 4.14.255-276-224.499.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 3 22:30:10 UTC 2022
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

I also tried forcing the Import command to look in the /module folder:

`Import-Module –Name \modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement -Verbose`

But that returned:

`The specified module was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.`

Comment: What is powershell version is this `$PSVersionTable` , are you sure its running powershell ?

Comment: @VasilNikolov see update to post.  PSVersion is 7.0.0

Comment: Use Save-Module to get a portable version of the module.  When you import-module point to the .PSD1.  You can use Find-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement | Install-module to get it from the repo.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron. Would you mind elaborating?  Do I first run Save-module for ExchangeOnlineManagement and then import-module?  Then the longer Find-Module... | Install-module command?  I see four commands and would deeply appreciate more information on how to properly use your suggestions.  Thank you!

Comment: have you tried these suggestions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412921/powershell-import-module-doesnt-find-modules

Comment: They created a lot easier to use [custom-pwsh-runtime announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-powershell-custom-runtime-for-aws-lambda/) -- You have the option of building your modules in another layer, or, you can copy them inline. there's examples of both in the repo