# PowerShell Profile Locations Built-in Directory/Folder Usage: How to Use Built-in Scripts directory?

Tags: powershell, default, built-in

I was recently investigating using [PowerShell profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.1), namely the profile found at `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\`. Here, there are two folders / directories that are built-in/out-of-the-box/default/already populated: `Modules\` and `Scripts\`. Based on [this SO post about where modules are stored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413557/22647714), it was clear that the `Modules\` directory is searched for with the [`Import-Module` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-5.1).

Does anyone know how to use the built-in `Scripts\` dir to load certain scripts or have them searchable out-of-the-box? I realize I can manually add that dir to my `%PATH%`/`$env:path`, but I assume if it's an out-of-the-box/default/built-in directory, that it would be used in some way or something already??

I'm hoping to understand where and how I can put scripts/code into that directory to make it accessible to call the script(s) I put in there whenever I've logged in and started up a PowerShell session. I understand that any modules I put into that `Modules\` directory can then be loaded in PowerShell using the `Import-Module` cmdlet... is there not some `Import-Script` or `MyScript.ps1` that would invoke any scripts put there by default?

However, I didn't seem to find anything on the Scripts directory, nor any guidance on how to use it. I tried googling around to no avail other than people saying to add it to the `$env:path` within the profile script, but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something—why would Microsoft/Windows make that folder/directory by default if it's not used in any way out-of-the-box?