# Get location of Powershell file that contains external function

Tags: powershell

I need to call out to a powershell function defined in a file in a separate folder. That function needs to use a dll located in the same folder. Is there any easy way to do this?

Details:

Structure:

- build\build.ps1
- tools\myTool\fileWithFunction.ps1
- tools\myTool\someDll.dll

build.ps1 has Include "...\tools\myTool\fileWithFunction.ps1"

It calls a function in that file. That function needs to load someDll.dll. I *could* pass the location of the folder (toos\myTool) in the function call, but was wondering if there's a way by which the function in fileWithFunction can figure out the location of the dll by itself (assuming that it's always in the same folder).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801967/how-can-i-find-the-source-path-of-an-executing-script

Comment: I actually have \tools\psake\psake calling build\build.ps1. Using the code in that post is giving me \tools\psake instead of \tools\myTool.

Comment: * ... \psake called by build\build.ps1

Answer (score 0):

Use `$PSScriptRoot`, this should get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're on PowerShell V2 (hopefully you're on at least v3), put this in fileWithFunction.ps1

```
$ScriptDir = {Split-Path $MyInvocation.ScriptName –Parent}
```

Then access the dir like so:

```
"ScriptDir is $(&$ScriptDir)"
```

The reason the scriptblock is used is to [ensure safety when dot sourcing script files.](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/determining-scriptdir-safely/)